# python multiprocessing peculiar memory management

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a simple multiprocessing code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time 

def worker(data):
    time.sleep(20)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numprocs = 10
    pool = Pool(numprocs)
    a = ['a' for i in xrange(1000000)]
    b = [a+[] for i in xrange(100)]

    data1 = [b+[] for i in range(numprocs)]
    data2 = [data1+[]] + ['1' for i in range(numprocs-1)]
    data3 = [['1'] for i in range(numprocs)]

    #data = data1
    #data = data2
    data = data3


    result = pool.map(worker,data)
```

`b` is just a large list. `data` is a list of length `numprocs` passed to pool.map, so I expect `numprocs` processes to be forked and each element of `data` to be passed to one of those. 
I test 3 different `data` objects: `data1` and `data2` have practically the same size, but when using `data1`, each process gets a copy of the same object, whereas when using `data2`, one process gets all of `data1` and others get just a '1' (basically nothing). `data3` is basically empty to measure the basic overhead cost of forking processes.

**Problem:**
The overall memory used is vastly different between `data1` and `data2`. I measure the amount of additional memory used by the last line (pool.map()) and I get:

1. `data1`: ~8GB
2. `data2`: ~0.8GB
3. `data3`: ~0GB

Shouldn't 1) and 2) be equal because the total amount of data passed to the children is the same. What is going on?

I measure memory usage from the `Active` field of /proc/meminfo on a Linux machine  (Total - `MemFree` gives the same answer)

Comment: You are mistaken on the use of `+[]` to make copies. First because the usual way of doing shallow copies is `a[:]` or `copy.copy`, and second because it seems you are expecting a deep copy and not a shallow one. Use [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) instead. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is a side effect of `pool.map` having to pickle each element in `data` in order to pass it to your child processes.

It turns out that `data1` is much larger than `data2` when you pickle it. Here's a small script that adds up the total pickled size of each element in each of your lists:

```
import pickle
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict

numprocs = 10
a = ['a' for i in range(1000000)]
b = [a+[] for i in range(100)]

data1 = [b+[] for i in range(numprocs)]
data2 = [data1+[]] + ['1' for i in range(numprocs-1)]
data3 = [['1'] for i in range(numprocs)]
sizes = OrderedDict()
for idx, data in enumerate((data1, data2, data3)):
    sizes['data{}'.format(idx+1)] = sum(sys.getsizeof(pickle.dumps(d))
                                            for d in data)

for k, v in sizes.items():
    print("{}: {}".format(k, v))
```

Output:

```
data1: 2002003470
data2: 200202593
data3: 480
```

As you can see, the total pickled size of `data1` is about ten times the size of `data2`, which exactly matches with the order of magnitude difference in memory usage between the two.

The reason `data2` pickles so much smaller is because of what Cilyan mentioned in the comments; you're actually making shallow copies when you create each `data` list:

```
>>> data2[0][2][0] is data2[0][0][0]
True
>>> data2[0][2][0] is data2[0][3][0]
True
>>> data2[0][2][0] is data2[0][4][0]
True
```

Now, `data1` is making shallow copies, too:

```
>>> data1[0][0] is data1[1][0]
True
>>> data1[0][0] is data1[2][0]
True
```

The key difference is that with `data2`, all the shallow copies are inside of one top-level element of the iterable (`data2[0]`). So when `pool.map` pickles that element, it can de-duplicate all the shallow copies into one single sub-list, and just pickle that one sub-list, along with metadata the describes how that sub-list is nested into `data2`. With `data1`, the shallow copies are across different top-level elements of `data1`, so `pool.map` pickles them individually, which means that the de-duplication is lost. So, when you unpickle `data1`, the shallow copies are gone, each element has a unique, but equal copy of the sub-list.

Compare these two examples, where `data1` and `data2` are identical to your lists:

```
>>> before_pickle1 = data1[0]
>>> before_pickle2 = data1[1]
>>> before_pickle1 is before_pickle2
False
>>> before_pickle1[0] is before_pickle2[0]
True  # The lists are the same before pickling
>>> after_pickle1 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(before_pickle1))
>>> after_pickle2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(before_pickle2))
>>> after_pickle1[0] is after_pickle2[0]
False  # After pickling, the lists are not the same
>>> before_pickle1 = data2[0]

>>> before_pickle1[0][0] is before_pickle1[1][0]
True
>>> after_pickle1 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(before_pickle1))
>>> after_pickle1[0][0] is after_pickle1[1][0]
True # The lists are still the same after pickling
```

This simulates the same pickling `pool.map` does. With `data1`, all of the de-duplication you had because of the shallow copies are lost, which makes the memory usage much higher.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. It was very helpful and solved my problem!