# keeping lists separate and avoiding shallow copy in python

Tags: python, shallow-copy

Here's my pseudo-code:

```
class foo(bar):
    def __init__(self, aList):
        bar.__init__(self, aList)
        self.initialList = aList
    def clock(self):
        modify(self.workingList)
        if(something):
            self.workingList = self.initialList
        assert self.initialList == range(10)

class bar(object):
    def __init__(self, aList):
        self.workingList = aList
```

A normal operation of the program will be like this:

```
a = range(10)
b = foo(a)
for i in xrange(10000):
    b.clock()
```

This did not work because when I did

```
self.workingList = self.initialList
```

self.workingList pointed to the same object instead of copying it. So then when I do

```
modify(self.workingList)
```

it also modifies the self.initialList, which is meant to stay the same.

My solution to that was to substitute

```
self.workingList = self.initialList
```

with

```
self.workingList = [i for i in self.initialList]
```

and I even replaced

```
self.initialList = aList
```

with:

```
self.initialList = [j for j in aList]
```

Although I believe this should work in principle, it didn't fix the problem in practice. I verify this via the assert statement. It seems like I'm misunderstanding some pythonic semantic. Could somebody please explain?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Notice that I understand the difference between deepcopy and shallowcopy. That's not what my question is about. I think something is getting messed up when I am using this in a class instantiation/inheritance. I am working offline to produce an MCV piece of code that I can provide here. Stay tuned for that update.

UPDATE:

I found the C in MCVE and here's the bug:

```
class bar(object):
    def __init__(self, aList):
        self.workingList = aList

class foo(bar):
    def __init__(self, aList):
        bar.__init__(self, aList)
        self.initialList = list(aList)
    def clock(self):
        self.workingList[2] = max(self.workingList[3], 2)
        #print self.workingList
        if(1):
            self.workingList = list(self.initialList)
        try:
                assert self.initialList == range(10)
        except:
                print self.initialList
                print self.workingList
                assert self.initialList == range(10)


a = range(10)
for i in xrange(10):
        b = foo(a)
        for j in xrange(100000):
                b.clock()
```

Comment: Can you provide an actual example of your proposed solution that *doesn't* work? Because what you did should make a copy of the list. (Incidentally, `list(aList)` is an easier way of making a copy. You might also see `list[:]` in some code.) Also, did you change *all* instances where you assign lists, such as the references to `self.initialList`?

Comment: @GregHewgill sure. What type of example would be helpful? Also, am I crazy, or what I did should suffice to keep those lists separate??

Comment: An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be most helpful.

Comment: Ok, let me work on that offline. I'll post it here as an EDIT/UPDATE to my question. Thanks!

Comment: The [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module has useful documentation on the subject.

Comment: And related (possibly duplicate?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm

Comment: downvoter care to comment??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So after a lot of debugging I found the reason for this bug. One possible fix is as follows:

```
class bar(object):
    def __init__(self, aList):
        self.workingList = list(aList) #aList
```

The reason for this is that python passes object references by value. Here's a [link](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/) that explains it pretty well.

The way it pertains to my code is that every time I change self.workingList in foo.clock():

```
modify(self.workingList)
```

it actually modifies the object that aList points to (outside of the constructor!!), so when I create a new instance of foo(aList), I am passing a new wrong version of aList into it. This is super tricky!

The  trickiest thing is that reassigning self.workingList does not create this bug (although it would in pass-by-reference), but modifying self.workingList does, because python passes object-references by value (all of this is explained with details in the [link](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/))