# Why does a[0] change?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I do:

```
a = [7,3,4]
b = a
b[0] = 10
```

`b[0]` is of course set to `10`, but `a[0]` is also set to `10`. Why is this?

Comment: Useful related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
b = a
```

This makes `b` and `a` reference to the same list object. If you want `b` to reference to a new list object that is a copy of `a`, try:

```
b = a[:]
```