# Original list gets modified in python

Tags: python

I have a simple code as below:

```
def swap(node):
    m00         = node[0][0]
    node[0][0]  = node[1][0]
    node[0][1]  = m00

originalList = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

# temp = list(originalList)
temp = originalList[:]

swap(temp)

print originalList
```

Initially I define a list with the values shown above and then copy this list to a temporary one. I have tried both methods of copying. Then I perform a swap function using `temp` list and print the original list again. As a result the original list is changed. What's the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: "both methods of copying": What would those be?

Comment: `originalList[:]` _does_ create a new copy of `originalList`. But it _doesn't_ create new copies of the lists inside `originalList`.

Comment: using `temp = list(originalList)` and `temp = originalList[:]`

Comment: In short: You create a copy of `originalList`, but not of the three lists contained in it (i.e., a shallow copy). Also see: [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

Comment: FWIW, you can simplify your `swap` by using tuple assignment: `node[0][0], node[0][1] = node[1][0], node[0][0]`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`originalList[:]` makes a copy of the *outer* list, but the 3 shorter lists.  You could make copies of them like so:

```
temp = [x[:] for x in originalList]
```

Answer (score 5):

The way you are copying the list (both ways) is known as a *shallow copy*.  This can be better seen this way:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6]
l3 = [7,8,9]
originalList = [l1,l2,l3]
temp = originalList[:]
l1[0] = 0

>>> temp
[[0, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> originalList
[[0, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

When you make a shallow copy of `originalList`, you are still getting references to `l1`, `l2`, and `l3`.  Any changes you make to those smaller lists will be reflected in both `originalList` and any shallow copies you make.  You want a *deep copy* operation.  For your purposes, Scott Hunter's answer of

```
temp = [x[:] for x in originalList]
```

will work.  In the general case, the method [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) from the `copy` module should get you a deep copy of whatever objects you need.  It is still likely better to use in this case as it is a few orders of magnitude faster.