# Python Dictionary in Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

```
>>> docsite = {'text1':1, 'text2':1}

>>> doc = {    
    'field1': docsite,
    'field2': docsite
}

>>> doc['field2']['text1'] += 2
```

after this when i print doc variable, i get

```
>>> doc
{'field2': {'text2': 1, 'text1': 3}, 'field1': {'text2': 1, 'text1': 3}}
```

I change value in field2 only. Somehow, values in field1 is also getting updated.

Question:

1. Why?
2. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `docsite` variable is a *reference* to a dictionnary, therefore, storing it at different locations (e.g. associated to different keys in another dictionary) will make them share the same dictionary in memory.

To resolve this, you may want to do a `copy` of your dictionary:

```
doc = {'field1': docsite, 'field2': docsite.copy()}
```

Note that, if in `docsite` you have references to other objects (`list`, other `dict`, etc) then you may have to use a `deepcopy`:

```
import copy
d2 = copy.deepcopy(docsite)
```

Answer (score 3):

Dict's are **mutable** objects in python. When you assign `dict` to other variable it's assigned **by reference**, what leads to problem you have described.

So in your case both values of keys in `doc` dict (field1,field2) point to same variable (`docsite`). That's way you have such behaviour.

To fix that use dict copy method before assigning it to `doc` keys.

```
docsite = {'text1':1, "text2":1}

doc = {    
"field1": docsite.copy(),
"field2": docsite.copy()
}
```

There are **two types of copies** in python, deepcopy and shallow copy ( see [that SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm?answertab=active#tab-top) to understand difference between them).

The example above is just **shallow** copy of `docsite`. However you can make **deepcopy** by using code below:

```
import copy


docsite = {'text1':1, "text2":1}

doc = {    
"field1": copy.deepcopy(docsite),
"field2": copy.deepcopy(docsite)
}
```

See [Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types-python?answertab=active#tab-top) that's good SO question to discover that topic for python...

Answer (score 2):

```
import copy
doc = {    
"field1":docsite,
"field2":copy.deepcopy(docsite)
}
```

Both keys in doc map to the same object, when you change the value of one key you are changing the docsite object, same object the other key also map to.

Answer (score 2):

Because the values in the `doc` dictionary refers the same dictionary object.

To solve, pass copies of the dictionaries, so that values refers different dictionary objects:

```
doc = {    
    "field1": dict(docsite),  # or docsite.copy()
    "field2": dict(docsite),  # or docsite.copy()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Python does not work with copy of object, when assigning your fields to `docsite`, both satellite values are pointing towards the same object. You can check using `id()` method: `id(doc['field2']) == doc['field1']`. Use `deepcopy` if you need different copy of your initial object.

```
import copy
doc['field2'] = copy.deepcopy(docsite)
```

**Update:** Of course, this will require to import the `copy` module in order to use it (as underlined by `Andriy Ivaneyko`).

Comment: that code would fails because `copy` module not imported.

Comment: @Andriy Ivaneyko, You are right. This answer does not intend to provide a full working code, it just underlines that mutable object are passed by reference and that why deepcopy exists. Is this a sufficient reason to downvote? Fixed anyway

Comment: you would confuse user without pointing to copy module, because it looks like `deepcopy` is are built-in method of python without such pointing...

Answer (score 1):

In your second dictionary you save the pointer to docsite. So, when you change it, it will change for all.

To solve it you have to copy.

```
doc = {    
    "field1":docsite.copy(),
    "field2":docsite.copy(),
}
```

I'm not sure about copy function, if it doesn't work just try to google ["python clone dictionary"](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+clone+dictionary&oq=python+clone+dictionary&aqs=chrome..69i57.131j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)