# Python sort function changes global variable when not supposed to

Tags: python, list, global-variables, bubble-sort, local-variables

So I have a list containing a number of elements, each of which are sublists containing two elements; a character and a number. 
Example:

```
unordered_list = [["A", 5], ["B", 3], ["C", 10], ["D", 0]]
```

I have a bubble sort function that orders the sublists in descending order, according to the value in index 1 of each sublist.

```
def list_sort(n):

    ordered = False
    passes = 0
    while not ordered:
        passes += 1
        ordered = True
        for i in range(0, len(n)-passes):
            if n[i][1] < n[i+1][1]:
                n[i], n[i+1] = n[i+1], n[i]
                ordered = False
    return n
```

The function works just fine, it's just that if I pass my unordered_list variable into the function in an assignment, ie;

```
sorted_list = list_sort(unordered_list)
sorted_list --> [["C", 10], ["A", 5], ["B", 3], ["D", 0]]
```

The sorted_list contains the results I'd expect, however the unsorted_list passed into the function is also ordered after the function call, which is not what I'd expect, as surely only the local variable n in the function and the sorted_list variable should be changed?

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

`n` continues to reference the original list, and since `n` is a mutable object, modifying via the reference will modify the referenced object.

You need to create a copy of the original list.

You can do this by *slicing*, before mutating the list:

```
def list_sort(n_original):
    n = n_original[:]
    # your code
    return n
```

`n_original[:]` is a *shallow* copy of list `n_original` which is synonymous to doing `n_original.copy()`. If you choose to be more verbose with the copy operation, you can use the builtin `copy` module.

```
from copy import copy

def list_sort(n_original):
    n = copy(n_original)
    # your code
    return n
```

For more on copying and their properties you can look at this:
[What exactly is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm)

Comment: I'm still confused as to why the global list is changed, when n is a local reference ?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of the [:] in the assignment of n?

Comment: @BrandonEdwards if you don't use the slicing, you don't actually create a new list but rather a new way of accessing the old one, a new way to reference it.

Comment: @BrandonEdwards `n` is a reference to the original list, not just a local reference. You will find this SO thread interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way to sort it while leaving the original unchanged:

```
unordered_list = [["A", 5], ["B", 3], ["C", 10], ["D", 0]]

sorted_list = sorted(unordered_list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

print(sorted_list)
# -> [['C', 10], ['A', 5], ['B', 3], ['D', 0]]

print(unordered_list)
# -> [['A', 5], ['B', 3], ['C', 10], ['D', 0]]
```

Comment: I think he wants to implement the algorithm by himself...

Comment: That makes sense, just thought I'd leave this alternative here in case :)

Comment: What's the 2nd parameter of that sorted function about??

Comment: @BrandonEdwards The``key`` is the function based on which you want to do the sorting. x[1] means based on the second value (the number) of every inner list.