# Referencing the function argument inside the same call

Tags: python

I have this kind of a function call in Python:

```
foo(["A", "B", "X", "Y", "Z"], SomeClass("m", ["A", "B", "X", "Y", "Z"]), SomeClass("n",["A", "B", "X", "Y", "Z"]))
```

In general, foo can have arbitrary number of arguments, so there can be many SomeClass objects passed, but when calling the constructor, you always have to pass the same thing that you pass as the first argument to foo, What I'd like to have is this:

```
foo(["A", "B", "X", "Y", "Z"], SomeClass("m", arg1), SomeClass("n", arg1))
```

So the code is shorter and more readable. What should I put instead of arg1 in order to "reference" the first argument passed to foo?

Comment: You could change the prototype of `foo`, so that it could be used like `foo(["A", "B", "X", "Y", "Z"], "m", "n")`, and internally `foo` would instantiate the different objects. Also, another solution would be to create variable `arg1`, and delete it after function call.

Comment: Sprine, you should add that as an answer. Your first solution is better than the ones answered so far.

Answer (score 4):

Why not to use variable:

```
arg1 = ["A", "B", "X", "Y", "Z"]
foo(arg1, SomeClass("m", arg1), SomeClass("n", arg1))
```

**NOTE**: lists passed by reference so if you modify it within `foo` or while initializing `SomeClass` you could get unpredictable result to avoid such case you have to pass copy of list, see more on that  [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python) question.

To fix reference problem you have to make copy of list prior passing it to `SomeClass` or `foo`, it can be done with [copy.copy()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy), [copy.deepcopy()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) or [list slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
from copy import copy, deepcopy


foo(copy(arg1), SomeClass("m", copy(arg1)), SomeClass("n", copy(arg1)))

foo(arg1[:], SomeClass("m", arg1[:]), SomeClass("n", arg1[:]))
foo(deepcopy(arg1), SomeClass("m", deepcopy(arg1)), SomeClass("n", deepcopy(arg1)))
```

Important moment is that list slicing (`[:]`) and `copy.copy()` return shallow copy of the list meanwhile `copy.deepcopy()` returns deep copy. See more on [What exactly is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm)

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no such references; you passed in a list literal object, there are no other references to it other than the internal interpreter stack.

Simply create your own reference; store that first list in a variable *first*, then reference that:

```
arg1 = ["A", "B", "X", "Y", "Z"]
foo(arg1, SomeClass("m", arg1), SomeClass("n", arg1))
```

If `foo()` is *always* going to need a number of `SomeClass()` instances based on `arg1`, you could also make `foo()` responsible for creating those instances. Pass in only that one *other* argument to `SomeClass()`:

```
foo(["A", "B", "X", "Y", "Z"], "m", "n")
```

and in `foo`:

```
def foo(arg1, *arg2_values):
    instances = [SomeClass(arg1, arg2) for arg2 in arg2_values]
```

Now the caller only has to pass in that list once.