# Create list of adjacent swap permutations

Tags: python, permutation

I'm looking for a function that would take a list such as [a,b,c,d] and output a list of all the permutations where adjacent indices are swapped i.e. [[b,a,c,d], [a,c,b,d],[a,b,d,c], [d,b,c,a]]

Thanks

Comment: Many people ask a question without writing any code,that will make SO like a coding service,but actually I think this is a good question.

It's worth to find a simple Pythonic way to do this.

Comment: Yeah I could have written code here but I learned from your solution as I am not an expert pythoner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way,you can just use a `for` loop and swap the adjacent items,`tmp=l[:]` will make a shallow copy,and it won't change original list `l`.

See more details from [What exactly is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm):

```
l=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for i in range(len(l)):
    tmp=l[:]
    tmp[i],tmp[i-1]=tmp[i-1],tmp[i]
    print tmp
```

Result:

```
['d', 'b', 'c', 'a']
['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']
```

Comment: Please try to keep meta commentary out of your answers.

Comment: is tmp=l[:] different than tmp=l ?

Comment: I think you can just do tmp[i],tmp[i-1]=tmp[i-1],tmp[i] instead of mod

Comment: @Rik `tmp=l[:]` make a shallow copy,`tmp=l` will change `l`,but `tmp=l[:]` won't,and yes  `tmp[i],tmp[i-1]=tmp[i-1],tmp[i]` is better.