# Deleting a dictionary item

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to delete an item without using `del`, and I have the following code for it.

```
d = {'Red': 1, 'Green': 2, 'Blue': 3} 

def removeKey(dicts, keys):
    for k,v in dicts.iteritems():
        if k!= keys:
            dicts.update({k:v})
        else:
            continue
    return dicts


print removeKey(d, 'Red')
```

This prints everything including 'Red'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not use pop method

Comment: have you tried the `pop` method on your dict?

Comment: Yes, I have and that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code never actually removes a key – instead, it just updates the original dictionary in-place if the key is not the key to remove; however, it doesn't do anything with the key to remove.

One option is to create a new dictionary:

```
def removeKey(dicts, keys):
    new_dict = {}
    for k,v in dicts.iteritems():
        if k != keys:
            new_dict[k] = v
    return new_dict
```

You also don't need the `else: continue` as that's implicit.

You can also condense this using a dictionary comprehension:

```
def removeKey(dicts, keys):
    return {k: v for k, v in dicts.iteritems() if k != keys}
```

Comment: I was attempting to create a new dictionary with all other keys except the key passed as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can deep copy the `dict` using the `copy` module to not modify the original `dict`, and `pop` the key from the copied `dict`:

```
from copy import deepcopy
d = {'Red': 1, 'Green': 2, 'Blue': 3}

def removeKey(d, key):
    d = deepcopy(d)
    d.pop(key, None)
    return d

print removeKey(d, 'Red')
# prints {'Green': 2, 'Blue': 3}
```

Comment: Any reasons for using deepcopy instead of just doing something like `d2= d.copy()` and `return d2` ?

Comment: d.copy() performs a shallow copy while deepcopy(d) performs a deep copy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm