# Understanding recursion and stacks in Python

Tags: python, recursion, stack, sudoku

I am developing a sudoku solver in Python.

```
def backtrack(puzzle):
    x,y,candidates=findSquare(puzzle)
    if x==-1 and y==-1:
        return puzzle #stop condition
    while len(candidates[x][y])>0:
        puzzle[x][y]=candidates[x][y].pop()
        puzzler=backtrack(puzzle)
        if isValid(puzzler):
            return puzzler
    return False
```

It is an algorithm that basicaly makes guesses. When a guess is wrong it goes to the next guess(the while loop).

The problem I have is the variable puzzle, the sudoku puzzle. When a guess is wrong, the while loop goes to the next candidates. The variable puzzle now includes the modifications made by the further steps of recursion, even though the steps were a false guess. I don't understand this, the other variable are unique to each recursion stack, shouldn't puzzle stay the same as well.

Don't hesitate to ask for additional explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The puzzle variable is a list. My guess is that every function backtrack uses the same puzzle (the same place in memory) because of shallow copy.
Here is a nice answer about shallow vs deep copy in Python.
[What exactly is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm)

More specifically the problem could be at line
puzzler=backtrack(puzzle)
I would try creating a deep copy of puzzle and give that to the recursion

Comment: Thank you, sir. deepcopy changed everything. puzzler=backtrack(copy.deepcopy(puzzle)) is the solution, thank you.