# Some basic python coding bug I don't know how to solve

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

I've encountered some problems when I was trying simulate school's math question,I've test the inner loop independently and the result is what I expect.I have no idea where is the problem and where can I get the resolution.It should be a simple bug.

**This is the question:**
There is a bag which includes three red balls ,four white balls and five black balls.Take one ball each time.Then what is the probability when red balls were the first color being collected.

**And This is my code:**(All annotations were not added in my code)

```
import random as rd
y = 1000    *//total try*
succ = 0    *//success times*
orgbg = ['r','r','r','w','w','w','w','b','b','b','b','b']    *//original bag for each loop initialization*
while (y >= 0):
    redball = 0
    blackball = 0
    whiteball = 0
    newbg = orgbg    *//every bag for a single try*
    while (redball < 3 and whiteball < 4 and blackball < 5):
        tknum = rd.randrange(0,len(newbg),1)
        tkball = newbg[tknum]
        if (tkball == 'r'):
            redball = redball + 1
        elif (tkball =='w'):
            whiteball = whiteball + 1
        else:
            blackball = blackball + 1
        del newbg[tknum]
    if (redball == 3):
        succ = succ + 1
    y = y - 1
print (succ)
```

This is what the error report says:
**ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)**

When I turn the code

```
tknum = rd.randrange(0,len(newbg),1)
```

into

```
tknum = rd.randrange(5,len(newbg),1)
```

The error reoprt says:
**ValueError: empty range for randrange() (5,5, 0)**

I guess it is the initialization in the outer loop **newbg = orgbg** doesn't work out,but how can that happen?

Sorry for giving such a length question ,I'm a beginner and this is the first time I ask question on StackOverFlow,you can also give me some suggestion on my code style or method and the way of asking question,next time I will be better,hope you don't mind.

Comment: This is the exact code causing the error? Also, posting the exact error with stack trace in the question would help. The last hardcoded argument to `randrange` is changing from the code to the error message.

Comment: What is the stack trace? Can you post?

Comment: The error says that your step size (third argument) is 0, but this doesn't match with your code.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/KevinLin/PycharmProjects/Practice/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    tknum = rd.randrange(0,len(newbg),1)
  File "C:\Users\KevinLin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\random.py", line 198, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)

Process finished with exit code 1

Is this the thing that you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is indeed linked with the initialization in the outer loop **newbg = orgbg**. To correct your code, you should modify this line with

```
newbg = deepcopy(orgbg)
```

and import the corresponding module at the start of your code:

```
from copy import deepcopy
```

The explanation of the bug is a bit complicated and is linked with the way that Python handles the memory when copying a list. In fact, there is two possibility for this: a shallow or a deep copy. Here, you made a shallow copy when a deep copy would have been necessary. It is better explained here: https://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php or [What exactly is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm)

Comment: you explanation is great, but instead of adding another import, you can just use **newbg = [*orgbg]**

Comment: Oh yes, it is a better solution in fact!