# How do I create a dictionary where every key is a value from a list, and every value is all the values from the list except the key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How do I create a dictionary where every key is a value from a list, and every value is all the values from the list except the key?

Example:

if I had

> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

how would I create the dictionary I described using for loops?

> d = {1: [2,3,4,5,6], 2: [1,3,4,5,6], 3: [1,2,4,5,6], 4: [1,2,3,5,6]}

I want to be able to do this using a for loop, but I don't even know where to start.

Comment: This looks like homework. Please review the guidelines here about posting homework questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/4138919. If it is not homework, please make a reasonable attempt and provide an update on what you've tried. A `for loop` seems like a reasonable place to start. I would review some documentation about Python lists (e.g. https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists), dictionaries, and basics of iteration/list enumeration.

Comment: This is actually cute in Haskell. Haskell uses association lists instead of dictionaries ([most of the time](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Map.html)) which are basically just tuples of `(key, value)`, so you can do `result xs = [(x, filter (/=x) xs) | x <- xs]` (where `(/=)` is the "not equal to" function and ` | x <- xs` is equivalent to `for x in xs`)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like homework, so I'm only going to give you the outline of a solution:

1. Create an empty dictionary
2. Loop through the list and add its elements and a copy of the entire list to as the value to the dictionary. Use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) in the standard library to copy the list.
3. Loop through the keys and values in your new dictionary and remove the key from the value.

Extra credit:

- Use a [dictonary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)(see towards the bottom of the section) to combine steps 1 and 2.
- [Learn the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17246744/2958070) between shallow copies and deep copies. In this specific example, would you have been safe with a shallow copy?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one line with a `dictionary comprehension`:

```
d = {i:[e for e in lst if e != i] for i in lst}
```

which, for your example, gives:

```
{1: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2: [1, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3: [1, 2, 4, 5, 6], 4: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6], 5: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6], 6: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Comment: Doesn't that break when the list isn't a range of consecutive numbers starting with 0?

Comment: @Ben Yes you are entirely write, there was confusion on my part. I have updated the answer now, and it is actually a shorter expression now!