# Adding sublist to list in python3 not working

Tags: python-3.x, list, append

I have a really weird issue in Python3. I have some code that generates some different list from a list of integers (what this does exactly is not relevant).

```
def get_next_state(state):

    max_val = max(state)
    max_index = state.index(max_val)
    new_state = state

    for n in range(max_val + 1):
        new_state[max_index] -= 1
        new_state[(n + max_index) % len(state)] += 1

    return new_state
```

Now all I want to do is add a next state to some list that keeps the states. This is my code:

```
l = [0, 2, 7, 0]
seen_states = []

for _ in range(10):
    print(l)
    seen_states += [l]
    l = get_next_state(l)

print(seen_states)
```

For some reason list `l` is assigned correctly when I print it, but it is not added correctly to the list of seen states. Note that I have also tried `seen_states.append(l)` instead of using `+= [l]`. Does anyone know why this happend?

Comment: Shouldn't your function `get_next_state()` return the new state?

Comment: Ah is does, (forgot to add that here). Will update the post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent these problems use [`copy`, `deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html) or `list[:]`

```
import copy

def get_next_state(state):

    max_val = max(state)
    max_index = state.index(max_val)
    new_state = copy.deepcopy(state)

    for n in range(max_val + 1):
        new_state[max_index] -= 1
        new_state[(n + max_index) % len(state)] += 1

    return new_state
```

You are sending your list `l` inside the function. When you assign it to another name, you are not making a copy but referencing the original object. Any modification on these lists is a change in the original object.

Comment: I added a link to the docs. There it explain the problem with mutable objects like lists

Answer (score 0):

Using `new_state = state[:]` (copies the list instead of referencing the original) in the `get_next_state` produces the following output:

```
[0, 2, 7, 0]
[2, 4, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 4, 1]
[2, 4, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 4, 1]
[2, 4, 1, 2]
[[0, 2, 7, 0], [2, 4, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 1, 2]]
```

Not sure if this is your desired output, as you did not specify what you are getting as "wrong" output

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the desired output. Do you know why leaving out the `[:]` in the statement: `new_state = state[:]` produces a wrong output?

Comment: You can look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17246744/8512629 it is a nice explanation on assignement vs deep and shallow copies