# I am copying one list to another in python. After that I am making a change in the second list

Tags: python

```
x = [[7, 8], 3, "hello", [6, 8], "world", 17] # List 1
w = list.copy(x) # copying list 1 to list 2
w[0][1] = 5 # changing the value in list 2
print(w)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
[[7, 5], 3, 'hello', [6, 8], 'world', 17]
[[7, 5], 3, 'hello', [6, 8], 'world', 17]
```

Changes to `w` are affecting `x` too.

Comment: Please edit your question as it's unreadable

Comment: in my understanding this is a duplicate of [shallow copy vs deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm)

Answer (score 1):

```
from copy import deepcopy
x = [[7, 8], 3, "hello", [6, 8], "world", 17]
w = deepcopy(x)

w[0][1] = 5 # changing the value in list 2
print(w)
print(x)
```

result:

```
[[7, 5], 3, 'hello', [6, 8], 'world', 17]
[[7, 8], 3, 'hello', [6, 8], 'world', 17]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `copy.deepcopy()` because `copy.copy()` only copies the references of the elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

`deepcopy` is the answer for your question :

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> x = [[7, 8], 3, "hello", [6, 8], "world", 17]
>>> x = [[7, 8], 3, "hello", [6, 8], "world", 17]
>>> w = deepcopy(x)
>>> w[0][1] = 5
>>> print(w)
[[7, 5], 3, 'hello', [6, 8], 'world', 17]
>>> print(x)
[[7, 8], 3, 'hello', [6, 8], 'world', 17]
```