# Predict iteratively from a list of scikit-learn models

Tags: python, list, for-loop, scikit-learn

I have two dataframes - one with predictors (`df_learn`), one with targets ( `target_learn`). I want to create a list of scikit-learn models (`ml_list`), one per target. So far, I have written this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor as GBM

df_learn = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[0,0,0,1,1,1], 'x2':[1,0,1,0,1,0], 'x3':[1,1,0,0,0,0]})
target_learn = pd.DataFrame({'y1':[1,0,0,2,2,0], 'y2':[1,1,1,0,1,0]})
target_colnames = ['y1', 'y2']
ml_list = [GBM(n_estimators = 5, max_depth= 2, min_samples_split= 2, 
            learning_rate=0.1, loss = 'ls')]*2
for i in [0,1] :
    ml_list[i] = ml_list[i].fit(df_learn, target_learn[target_colnames[i]])
```

To check this, I created a list of predictions.

```
pred_list = []

for i in [0,1] :
    pred_list.append(ml_list[i].predict(df_learn))

pd.DataFrame.from_items(zip(target_colnames, pred_list))
```

The result surprised me, as I got the exact same predictions for both targets.

```
y1      y2
0.80317 0.80317
0.80317 0.80317
0.80317 0.80317
0.39366 0.39366
0.80317 0.80317
0.39366 0.39366
```

When I ran each model separately (without using a list), I had two distinct predictions.

```
m1 = GBM(n_estimators = 5, max_depth= 2, min_samples_split= 2, 
            learning_rate=0.1, loss = 'ls')
m2 = GBM(n_estimators = 5, max_depth= 2, min_samples_split= 2, 
            learning_rate=0.1, loss = 'ls')
m1 = m1.fit(df_learn, target_learn['y1'])
m2 = m2.fit(df_learn, target_learn['y2'])
p1 = m1.predict(df_learn)
p2 = m2.predict(df_learn)
pd.DataFrame.from_items(zip(target_colnames, [p1,p2]))
```

Which gave the following results.

```
y1       y2
0.710278 0.80317
0.608147 0.80317
0.567309 0.80317
0.901585 0.39366
1.311095 0.80317
0.901585 0.39366
```

Obviously, at least one of the `for` loop seems to overwrite the result of the previous member in the list. I assume this has to be related to some copy/deep-copy issue. How should I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
ml_list = [GBM(n_estimators = 5, max_depth= 2, min_samples_split= 2, 
            learning_rate=0.1, loss = 'ls')]*2
```

Python is making a shallow copy of the object to fill the list with 2 elements. But both of the variables essentially reference to the same underlying object.

So when you do this:

```
for i in [0,1] :
    ml_list[i] = ml_list[i].fit(df_learn, target_learn[target_colnames[i]])
```

The underlying GBM object is refit each time. So it only remembers the last call to fit, i.e. when i = 1

You can change that by adding two distinct objects to the list and not using `* 2`

```
ml_list = [GBM(n_estimators = 5, max_depth= 2, min_samples_split= 2, 
            learning_rate=0.1, loss = 'ls'),
           GBM(n_estimators = 5, max_depth= 2, min_samples_split= 2, 
            learning_rate=0.1, loss = 'ls')]
```

Then you will get different results for each i as you are getting above.

See this question for more information about shallow and deep copies:-

- [What exactly is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm)

To fill the list with same type of estimators, scikit has a [clone method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.clone.html) which will return a new object same as provided. You can do:

```
est = GBM(n_estimators = 5, max_depth= 2, min_samples_split= 2, 
            learning_rate=0.1, loss = 'ls')
ml_list = []

from sklearn.base import clone
for i in range(50):
    ml_list.append(clone(est))
```

Comment: That was my thought at some point. So basically it's impossible to create the list without typing n times the number of models you need ? (For the purpose of the example, I left 2 targets but actually, I am dealing with 12 targets, and may have to do it for potentially >50 ones...)

Comment: @AshOfFire I have edited the answer to include the solution to your use-case