# Why list of lists is a reference to object when you use list.copy() but 1d list is just a copy?

Tags: python, list

Here a screenshot of output. Please explain why it works this way and provide me with a solution on how to make the copy of a list of lists

[the result of work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abUZF.png)

```
matrix = [['I','A','O','O','I'],['I','A','O','O','I'],['I','A','O','O','I'],['I','A','O','O','I'],['I','A','O','O','I']]

matrix_1d = ['I','A','O','O','I']

matrix2 = matrix.copy()
matrix2_1d = matrix_1d.copy()
def printMat(m):
    for i in range(len(m)):
        print (m[i])

matrix[0][0] = 'lol'
matrix2[0][1] = 'kek'

matrix_1d[0] = 'lol'
matrix2_1d[1] = 'kek'

printMat(matrix)
print("_")
printMat(matrix2)
print("_")
print(matrix_1d)
print("_")
print(matrix2_1d)
```

Comment: Your output and code are both text, don't post links to screenshot of it. Copy paste them into the question

Comment: `.copy` creates a shallow copy. The inner objects are not copied, a reference to them is put in a *new list*. You want a *deep copy*.

Comment: As per @juanpa.arrivillaga  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) clearly states:

> Return a shallow copy of the list.

What you want instead is a **deep** copy.

Comment: Thanks !
But why I have copies in 1d list if i should have references to initial list?

Comment: @BorysAltynnyk it works **exactly** the same. Your "1-d" list copy has references to the items in the original list, just as your "2-d" list copy does. You can check the `id`'s for yourself. And they aren't references to the *initial list*, they are references to the *objects contained by the original list*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. But if objects of new list are references to objects of the initial list, why changing them in copy list don't affect them in the initial list? (Have a look on the picture attached, you will understand what I am talking about)

Comment: @BorysAltynnyk you never try to change them. You *change the list*. Where do you believe you try to change the objects in the "1-D" list?

Comment: @BorysAltynnyk When you do `matrix2_1d[1] = 'kek'`, you assign the reference at index `1` of the copied list to point to a different object. **This does not change the object referenced by the original list**. Nor does it change any reference in the original list.