# How to copy some elements from a list-of-list so that is doesn't affect the value of elements in the copied list

Tags: python

What I want to do is to copy some elements of one list-of-list to other based on certain conditions and then change the original list of lists

```
arr = [[1,0,4],[1,2,65],[2,3,56],[11,14,34]]
brr = []

for x in range(0,len(arr)):
    if arr[x][1] < 10:
        brr.append(arr[x])
        arr[x][1] = 1000
print(brr)
```

O/P:

> [[1, 1000, 4], [1, 1000, 65], [2, 1000, 56]]

in the above example, I wanted to copy all the list with the middle element <10 to another list-of-list `brr` and then change the element in the original list to a large value. However, when I change a value in the original list it also changes the value in the second list

I know that when I append arr[i] to brr, brr just stores the reference pointers to the lists in arr and hence when the values at those addresses are changed it reflects at both the places,

also, if I had to copy the entire l-o-l I could have done it with deepcopy, but what is the best way to do it if there is a criteria /condition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way of copying lists, along with a more pythonic way of iterating through a list

```
arr = [[1, 0, 4], [1, 2, 65], [2, 3, 56], [11, 14, 34]]
brr = []

for x in arr:
    if x[1] < 10:
        brr.append(list(x))
        x[1] = 1000
print(brr)
# [[1, 0, 4], [1, 2, 65], [2, 3, 56]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from copy import deepcopy
#....
brr.append(deepcopy(arr[x]))
```

Comment: Doesn't  `deepcopy` take an argument? Also don't you invoke it like `copy.deepcopy(<list tocopy>)` ?  Do lists have a `deepcopy` fn ?

Answer (score 3):

You should create a deep copy of each (inner) list from *arr* that you want to copy. One way (which is *the shortest to write*, as there are numerous: check [[SO]: How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)), is via slicing:

Translated to your code, you should replace

```py
brr.append(arr[x])
```

by

```py
brr.append(arr[x][:])
```

**Note**: If you want to be generic / scalable, you should go for `copy.deepcopy`, as it would also work if one of `arr[x]`'s elements wold be itself a list (which currently isn't the case).