# numpy slice assign to another value

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a 1D numpy array:

```
 arr = np.arange(10)
```

Then I slice arr and assign to another variable:

```
 arr2 = arr[5:8]
```

And I want to change arr :

```
 arr2 *= 10
```

or:

```
 arr2 = arr2 * 10
```

The results are different. Why are they different?

```
 arr
```

array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 50, 60, 70,  8,  9])

```
 arr
```

array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm)

Comment: references are pretty funny. well try doing `arr2 = arr[5:8].copy()`

Comment: @AnshulVerma, with numpy arrays the distinction between a `view` and a `copy` is more important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simplified terms, `arr2 = arr[5:8]` assigns a reference to the `5:7`th elements of `arr` to a variable `arr2`.

Thus the operation `arr2 *= 10` boils down to "multiply those elements by 10 in place", which modifies `arr` in place (you are performing an in-place operation, a modification, on a reference, which therefore affects the original).

However, `arr2 = arr2 * 10` says "take the result of multiplying the 5:7th elements by 10, then assign it to a variable called `arr2`". Here, you perform an operation on a reference (*not* a modification), take the output (to be explicit, the operation `arr2 * 10` returns a new object), and assign it to `arr2`, which incidentally destroys the original reference (but this part is somewhat irrelevant).

Or compare these:

```
arr[5:8] *= 10
arr[5:8] = arr[5:8] * 10
arr2 = arr[5:8] * 10
```

The first two are equivalent. Your code is essentially a comparison between the first and the third (equivalently, the second and third). The second and third are not equal, because in your code, your earlier assignment of `arr2 = arr[5:8]` has nothing to do with the LHS of `arr2 = arr[5:8] * 10`.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [639]: arr = np.arange(10)
```

By indexing with a slice (basic indexing), `arr2` is a `view` of `arr`.  It shares the data buffer with `arr`:

```
In [640]: arr2 = arr[5:8]                                                                             
In [641]: arr2                                                                                        
Out[641]: array([5, 6, 7])
```

If we make a copy, values are copied, not shared:

```
In [642]: arr3 = arr[5:8].copy()     # arr[[5,6,7]] is also a copy
```

By modifying `arr2` in-place, we also modify part of `arr`:

```
In [643]: arr2 *= 10                                                            
In [644]: arr2                                                                                        
Out[644]: array([50, 60, 70])
In [645]: arr                                                                                         
Out[645]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 50, 60, 70,  8,  9])
```

But not `arr3`:

```
In [646]: arr3                                                                                        
Out[646]: array([5, 6, 7])
```

`arr2 = arr2*10` does not modify the `arr2` array, but rather assigns a whole new array to the `arr2` variable.

So you need to understand what it means to assign an object to a variable.  The difference between assign a variable, and modifying a mutable object.  And the difference between array copy and view (and between basic and advanced indexing).  This last one is specific to `numpy`, the rest to Python as well.