# is there any difference df=DF.copy() and df=DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i want copy DataFrame to another

there is 2 method to copy DataFrame to another 
which method is good and sad

```
label=train.copy()

label=train
```

Comment: `copy()` gives you a copy with different memory allocation. `label = train` only gives you an alias, that is, same memory, and if you change `label`, say `label.iloc[0] = 0`, you change `train` as well.

Comment: Yes.  The first copy data to a new memory location. The second just creates a new pointer to the same object in its current memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm)

Comment: Note: it is better to think of python names as acting as keys in various symbol tables, 'namespaces', which are often implemented as literal `dict` objects, and assignment as moving various pointers around various symbol tables.

Comment: TL:DR `label=train` does *not* copy at all, whereas `.copy` does.