# Why Python 2D array access modifies the whole column

Tags: python-3.x

I had a confusion where I initialize a 2D array in this way:

```
>>> a = [[0] * 3] * 3
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> a[0][0] = 1
>>> a
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

while I was expecting it to be

```
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

I also tried

```
>>> a = [[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> a[0][0] = 1
>>> a
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Which worked as expected

Wonder what is the reason caused this?

Comment: Because in the first code, the x3 is making 3 references of the same list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the outter `*3` you are making a shallow copy of a list.

This can be easily verifier by printing ids. An id is unique to each item.

```
a = [[0] * 3] * 3
print(*map(id, a))
# Same ID
```

Instead, you absolutely need to generate new lists

```
a = [[0] * 3 for _ in range(3)]
print(*map(id, a))
# Different ids
```

If you want more information you can check this question : [What exactly is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm)

Comment: Always thought they are equivalent, thanks for your answer.