# Shallow copy operation confusion

Tags: python

I am trying to understand behind the code operation in shallow copy in python

created an object

```
o = [1,12,32,423,42,3,23,[1,2,3,4]]
```

created a shallow copy and assigned to a variable

```
r = copy.copy(o)

print(r)
[1, 12, 32, 423, 42, 3, 23, [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Then tried to assigning new value in two different indexes

```
o[1]="ff"
o[7][1]="kk"


print(r)
[1, 12, 32, 423, 42, 3, 23, [1, 'kk', 3, 4]]
```

So as per shallow copy it creates reference of parent in child variable so when we change parent, it reflects in child, but here reference changed only in sublist only. Why so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm)

Comment: Your example has covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50198542/8353711)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to observe what is happening by running the below code (after the modifications):

```
print(id(r[1]))
print(id(o[1]))    # different

print(id(r[7]))
print(id(o[7]))    # same

print(id(r[7][1]))
print(id(o[7][1])) # same
```

Also, read the links that others have posted.

Comment: i tried to print ids before assigning to their index o = [1,12,32,423,42,3,23,[1,2,3,4]]
r = copy.copy(o)

print(id(o[1]),id(r[1])) . O/P is 1774052288 1774052288 same

Comment: Also, print after the modifications.

Comment: okay so after modification ids are 69169280 1774052288, different... So, in list id changes of respective index but in sublist id remains same. But Why?

Comment: To understand that, try to run this code and observe: "import sys

arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
print(sys.getsizeof(arr1))

arr2 = [1, 2, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
print(sys.getsizeof(arr1))
"