# Want to remove object itself from list in Python

Tags: python, list

I am very new to programming and not good at English. plz understand even if I make mistakes.
here is my question, I want to remove object is self form list. 
how can I get result as like first one I tried 
even though I switch to asd=ad_material_name2

what I tried is

```
ad_material_name=['a', 'b', 'c']
ad_material_name2=['a', 'b', 'c']

for aa in ad_material_name:  
    asd=['a', 'b', 'c']
    asd.remove(aa)
    print(asd)
```

it's result came out like this

```
['b', 'c']
['a', 'c']
['a', 'b']
```

so, I thought it worked. but, when I tried this

```
ad_material_name=['a', 'b', 'c']
ad_material_name2=['a', 'b', 'c']

for aa in ad_material_name:  
    asd=ad_material_name2
    asd.remove(aa)
    print(asd)
```

it came out like this.

```
['b', 'c']
['c']
[]
```

I thought from here it might be a problem of ad_material_name=['a', 'b', 'c']=ad_material_name2
and it some how effect result. 
so, I tried this.

```
ad_material_name=['a', 'b', 'c']
ad_material_name2=['a', 'b', 'c', 'b']

for aa in ad_material_name:  
    asd=ad_material_name2
    asd.remove(aa)
    print(asd)
```

but, it came out like this

```
['b', 'c', 'd']
['c', 'd']
['d']
```

how can I get result as like first one I tried 
even though I switch to asd=ad_material_name2

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper/17246744#17246744

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modify

```
asd=ad_material_name2
```

to

```
asd=ad_material_name2.copy()
```

so that the "remove" opertion will not modify the list ad_material_name2 directly.

Answer (score 2):

You might use [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function from itertools to achieve the same result.

```
from itertools import combinations

ad_material_name=['a', 'b', 'c']

for x, y in combinations(ad_material_name, r=2):
    print([x, y])
```

or if you need to create ad_material_name2 variable and assign permutations to it, you can do following:

```
from itertools import combinations

ad_material_name=['a', 'b', 'c']

ad_material_name2 = [[*comb] for comb in combinations(ad_material_name, r=2)]

print(ad_material_name2)

# output
[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your second code is that Python lists are mutable; they can be changed. Assigning a variable to a list, and then changing the variable- changes the list as well.
e.g:

```
def make123(array):
    array[2] = 3
    array[1] = 2
    array[0] = 1

e = [3, 5, 6]
make123(e)

print(e) # [1, 2, 3]
```

You might wanna use a tuple, then convert it to a list:

```
ad_material_name=['a', 'b', 'c']
ad_material_name2=('a', 'b', 'c')

for aa in ad_material_name:  
    asd=list(ad_material_name2)
    asd.remove(aa)
    print(asd)
"""
['b', 'c']
['a', 'c']
['a', 'b']
"""
```

Answer (score -1):

It's the difference that comes from deep copy and shallow copy.
Your problem will be solved by using deepcopy.

```
import copy
ad_material_name=['a', 'b', 'c']
ad_material_name2=['a', 'b', 'c', 'b']

for aa in ad_material_name:
    asd=copy.deepcopy(ad_material_name2)
    asd.remove(aa)
    print(asd)
```

Comment: Your query is not clear. Perhaps some more details needed.

Comment: A deepcopy isn't necessary here, the OP simply wasnt copying, a shallow copy would have worked fine.