# What is the difference between shallow copy and '=' in Python?

Tags: python, copy

```
  x = Object1
  b = Object2
```

What is the difference between

```
 import copy

 x = b
 x = copy.copy(b)
```

Comment: `x = b` isn't a copy at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper)

Answer (score 0):

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object
>   [copy doc @python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

Thus if you really want to have the same object twice without any bindings between you can use the copy package.