# Assigning certain variable, then value to nested dictionary without modifing the original variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

To the point, i got two events:

`a = {'key': 'a', 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 15, 11, 18, 18, 982000)}`

`b = {'key': 'b', 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 11, 47, 14, 522000)}`

my goal is to assign and nest one event to the other like this:

`a['key2'] = b`

and this is result:

`{'key': 'a', 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 15, 11, 18, 18, 982000), 'key2': {'key': 'b', 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 11, 47, 14, 522000)}}`

but when i want to assign new key to nested it works but it does also modify variable b, **result**:

`a['key2']['nestedkey'] = {'somekey': 'somevalue'}`

`{'key': 'a', 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 15, 11, 18, 18, 982000), 'key2': {'key': 'b', 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 11, 47, 14, 522000), 'nestedkey': {'somekey': 'somevalue'}}}`

`{'key': 'b', 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 11, 47, 14, 522000), 'nestedkey': {'somekey': 'somevalue'}}`

Can someone explain why variable b is getting modified? And if there is anyway to do it without modifying it?

Comment: `a['key2']` refers to the *same* dictionary as `b`, so when you change one, you are changing the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python by default you're not making a copy of an object when you assign it. So when you're doing `a['key2'] = b`, `a['key2]` just hold a reference to `b`. Weather you modify `b` or `a['key2']` it's going to modify the same object.

To make a copy you can use deepcopy:

```py
import copy

a['key2'] = copy.deepcopy(b)
```

Then it would works as you are expecting, modifying `a['key2']` will not modify `b`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of variable b is being used by reference. Basically `a['key2']=b` says that `a['key2']` points to the location in memory where b is stored, so when changes are made to `a['key2']` or the variable `b` the same data is being changed.

To avoid this you can make a deep copy of of b and assign that to `a[key2]` like so:

```
import copy

a[key2] = copy.deepcopy(b)
```

This should give you your desired results.

To get more details about how `copy` works see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper)