# Iterate through if statements

Tags: python, if-statement, iteration, discord.py

I have made a bot which automatically authenticates users for me

It goes to my autobuy API url and then gets the `response`.

This is my code

```
if response['productId'] == "b936596e-8cdf-4090-78b7-08d7a3ec0911":
   await message.author.add_roles(onetap)

elif response['productId'] == "d66e3b18-4b14-4396-d9a6-08d7cb20b1e4":
    await message.author.add_roles(otc)

elif response['productId'] == "69f4b63b-b0cd-4ef1-7872-08d7a3ec0911":
    await message.author.add_roles(aimware)

elif response['productId'] == "f1c36a82-d8dd-422d-135b-08d7ca2ec9fd":
    await message.author.add_roles(personal)

await message.author.send('Your key has been validated. {0.author.mention}, please look at the #read-this channel to see how to download your config.'.format(message))
await message.author.remove_roles(auth)
await message.delete()
```

The problem here is that when the first `if` statement is true so the `productID` = `f1c36a82-d8dd-422d-135b-08d7ca2ec9fd` then everything goes as I want. However, if this is not the case and the `productID` is the second, third or fourth strings then nothing happens. I am not getting any errors but the program just doesn't do what I want it to

Comment: If it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper

Comment: You mean if last `if` condition is true it works fine? Have you checked the special characters/spaces in the IDs you are trying to match as I could not think of any other issue here

Comment: yes they are correct

Comment: tldr: I found out the commerce site I use has a bug

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. :( Voting to close as not reproducible.