# Variable's value changing unexpectedly during recursion (MERGE SORT)

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

Given an input array :

```
[49, 86, 78]
```

My code should return:

```
[[49,1],[78,2],[86,1]]
```

That is, it should order the array according the first number in each sub array, the second one will be used as an index for later use. I decided to use merge sort for sorting. Here is my code (I know its ugly but please run it once):

```
def merge_sort(array):
    print("array>>>", array)
    if len(array[:,0]) == 1:
        print('going back')
        return
    arrL = array[0:int(len(array)/2),:]
    arrR = array[int(len(array)/2):,:] 
    print('left>>', arrL, 'right>>', arrR)
    print("*****************")
    print('into left')
    merge_sort(arrL)
    print("*****************")
    print('into right')
    merge_sort(arrR)
    print("*****************")
    print('into MERGE')
    merge(array, arrL, arrR)
    print('going back')

def merge(A, arrL, arrR):
    print("array ", A, "left", arrL, "right", arrR)
    i = 0
    while len(arrL[:,0]) is not 0 and len(arrR[:,0]) is not 0:
        print('ARRAYLEFT>>', arrL, 'ARRAYRIGHT>', arrR)
        if arrR[0,0] < arrL[0,0]:
            print(arrR[0,0], 'is less than', arrL[0,0])
            A[i] = arrR[0]
            arrR = arrR[1:,:]
            print('A>>', A, 'arrR>>', arrR, 'ARRAYLEFT>>', arrL)
        else:
            print(arrL[0,0], 'is less than', arrR[0,0])
            A[i] = arrL[0]
            arrL = arrL[1:,:]
            print('A>>', A, 'arrL>>', arrL)
        i += 1

    print('ARRAYLEFT>>', arrL, 'ARRAYRIGHT>>', arrR)

    if len(arrL[:,0]) == 0 :
        print('left exhaused')
        print('A>>', A, 'arrR>>', arrR)
        A[i:,:] = arrR
        print('A>>', A, 'arrR>>', arrR)

    elif len(arrR[:,0]) == 0:
        print('right exhaused')
        print('A>>', A, 'arrL>>', arrL)
        A[i:,:] = arrL
        print('A>>', A, 'arrL>>', arrL)

    print('after merge', A)
    return
```

---

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
input_array = [np.random.choice(np.arange(100)) for _ in range(5)]
print(input_array)
```

outputs:

```
[37, 12, 72, 9, 75]
```

then,

```
new_array = np.array(list( map(list, zip(input_array, [x for x in range(len(input_array)) ])) ))
print(new_array)
```

outputs:

```
array([[37,  0],
       [12,  1],
       [72,  2],
       [ 9,  3],
       [75,  4]])
```

and finally,

```
merge_sort(new_array)
```

gives the following (I have added only the part of interest). **Notice how once we go `into MERGE`  the value of arrL changes to the value of arrR once arrR becomes []** marked in the code by `<<<===` sign:

```
array>>> [[37  0]
 [12  1]
 [72  2]
 [ 9  3]
 [75  4]]
left>> [[37  0]
 [12  1]] right>> [[72  2]
 [ 9  3]
 [75  4]]
*****************
into left
array>>> [[37  0]
 [12  1]]
left>> [[37  0]] right>> [[12  1]]
*****************
into left
array>>> [[37  0]]
going back
*****************
into right
array>>> [[12  1]]
going back
*****************
into MERGE
array  [[37  0]
 [12  1]] left [[37  0]] right [[12  1]]
ARRAYLEFT>> [[37  0]] ARRAYRIGHT>> [[12  1]]  <<<=== # arrL = [[37  0]]
12 is less than 37
A>> [[12  1]
 [12  1]] arrR>> [] ARRAYLEFT>> [[12  1]]
ARRAYLEFT>> [[12  1]] ARRAYRIGHT>> []       <<<=== # arrL = [[12  1]]
right exhaused
A>> [[12  1]
 [12  1]] arrL>> [[12  1]]
A>> [[12  1]
 [12  1]] arrL>> [[12  1]]
after merge [[12  1]
 [12  1]]
going back
*****************
## .... and so one....
```

This error seems to occur whenever the code goes `into MERGE` and `arrR = []` so after this

```
print(new_array)
```

outputs:

```
array([[ 9,  3],
       [ 9,  3],
       [ 9,  3],
       [ 9,  3],
       [75,  4]])
```

which is clearly the wrong answer. Please help me understand where I am making a mistake... I have been staring at the code and the output for a good 20 minutes now but can't seem to find it. Any suggestion/criticism would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for adding so many print statements... I was trying to debug the code but to no avail

Comment: IMHO you overcomplicate this operation, interested in a an one-line solution (without importing libs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's kinda hard to understand, mainly due to similar print messages in different places. The issue seems to be connected with the fact that `A[0]` and `arrL` are the same arrays. That would not be the case with plain python lists, but numpy seems to do some sort of optimization to save memory. So when you modify `A[i] = arrR[0]`,  you basically assign `arrL = arrR`. 
Besides that, the implementation seems to be pretty unusual for the merge sort algorithm. You need neither NumPy nor 2d array, just a list of numbers is what you want to sort. 
If you just want a sorted list, you can use the built-in implementation, sorted(array). 
Finally, I would kindly recommend getting used to the debugger (one in your IDE, or PDB https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/ ) instead of print statements, it is a much more effective way to understand what the code is doing. It may be hard at first, but trust me, it will pay off and help you to progress as a developer. Stay safe.

Comment: So, to fix the issue, you can add ```arrL = array[0:int(len(array)/2),:].copy()``` (also for arrR, obviously) , but I advise you to rewrite the code to use plain lists, and make it more clear, so you can see even without the print what the code is doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. Also thanks for the tip about using a debugger... I am still fairly new to python so i didn't know such a tool existed.. I am very grateful and will learn about it ... Thanks again

Comment: `That would not be the case with plain python lists..` One point to note, Python lists can also behave similar to this if it is not a [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17246744/1589191).

Comment: @EmilMGeorge Thanks for pointing that out, what I wanted to say is that @Yatin has used ```array[0:1, :]```, which must make a copy in case of ```list[0:1][:]```, and actually ```id(A[0]) != id(arrL)```, but it still modifies both arrays. Numpy is doing some kind of magic underneath and I was not aware about it as well.

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov Yes you are right about numpy. It seems `id(array[0]) == id(array[1])`. That is interesting. Have to see how numpy does it. Just to clarify my previous comment, what I meant was that `listb = lista[0:1][:]` would only make a shallow copy of `lista`. Doing `listb[0] += [...]` would change `lista[0]` too. But yes, I agree that in this case, lists should work ok, because here we would be assigning another list (`=`) not mutating (`+=`). I intended it as more of a _related note_ kind of comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding .copy() everywhere solved my problem.

```
def merge(A,arrL,arrR):
    i = 0
    while len(arrL[:,0]) is not 0 and len(arrR[:,0]) is not 0:
        if arrR[0,0] < arrL[0,0]:
            A[i] = arrR[0].copy()
            arrR = arrR[1:,:].copy()
        else:
            A[i] = arrL[0].copy()
            arrL = arrL[1:,:].copy()
        i+=1

    if len(arrL[:,0]) == 0 :
        A[i:,:] = arrR.copy()

    elif len(arrR[:,0]) == 0:
        A[i:,:] = arrL.copy()

    return 

def merge_sort(array):
    if len(array[:,0]) == 1:
        return
    arrL = array[0:int(len(array)/2),:].copy()
    arrR = array[int(len(array)/2):,:] .copy()
    merge_sort(arrL)
    merge_sort(arrR)
    merge(array,arrL,arrR)
```