# Python: How do I avoid my global variable from being updated when passing it through a function?

Tags: python

Below is a simplified version of my problem:

```
example =[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]

def func(data):
    data[0][0:6] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    data[1][0:6] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    return data    

print(example)
func(example)
print(example)
```

and has the output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

The output I am expecting is:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

How do I avoid the global variable "example" from being updated after running "func"? I have tried a number placeholder variable combinations (inside and outside "func") and all have the same result - an updated "example".

Comment: It looks like you could use a [quick guide](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) to the relationship between variables and objects in Python. Python doesn't implicitly copy objects all over the place like, say, C++.

Comment: Try using shallow copy - pass `copy.copy(example)` to the function.

Comment: Also it’s not just a global variable that could be affected like this - it’s how Python works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

While you should avoid using globals, if you absolutely need to do the above, use `deepcopy()`:

```
from copy import deepcopy

example =[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]

def func(data):
    data = deepcopy(data)
    data[0][0:6] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    data[1][0:6] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    return data

print(example)
func(example)
print(example)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using deep copy:

```
import copy
example =[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]

def func(data):
    data[0][0:6] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    data[1][0:6] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    return data    

print(example)
func(copy.deepcopy(example))
print(example)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because lists are mutable, they are basically passed by reference to `func`. If you want to act on a different copy of that object, you need to explicitly make such a copy (other answers say the same, but for your case you probably want that *inside* the function):

```
import copy

example =[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]

def func(data):
    localdata = copy.deepcopy(data). ## or data.copy() or copy.copy(data)
    localdata[0][0:6] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    localdata[1][0:6] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    return localdata    

print(example)
newexample = func(example)
print(example)
```

Whether you want `copy.copy(data)` or `copy.deepcopy(data)` or `data.copy()` [depends on what you know about the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper).

Note also that your original code doesn't use its `return` for anything...

Comment: Python argument passing mechanics don't change depending on whether the argument is mutable. (If it looks like they do, that's because of the operations you're testing. Comparisons like `x = 3` vs `y[0] = 4` are misleading - `y[0] = 4` isn't an assignment to `y`.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That is correct, of course, but I didn't feel it was particularly helpful to go into the semantics of Python name binding which underlies all of this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a copy for this to work. And since `example` is a list of lists, you have to either use `copy.deepcopy()` or list comprehensions, like the following:

```
example =[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]

def func(data):
    dataCopy = [sublist.copy() for sublist in data]
    dataCopy[0][0:6] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    dataCopy[1][0:6] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    return dataCopy    

print(example) # all 0's
func(example)
print(example) # still all 0's

print(func(example)) # all 1's
```