# Python's list subtle trick?

Tags: python, list, del

I embrace to study Python thorugh the course material of pythoninstitute.org and one of the quizes consist of:

```
l1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
l2 = l1
l3 = l2
del l1[0]
del l2[:]
print(l3)
```

I expected ['B'. 'C'] as result of print(l3), meanwhile the correct result is [].

I don't understand why. Could you explain that to me?

To get what I expected that result I had to code as it follows:

```
l1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
l2 = l1
l3 = l2
del l1[0]
l4 = l2[:]
del l4
print(l3)
```

Could you explain the difference between the two snippet?

Comment: `l3 = l2` does _not_ copy `l2`, nor does `l2 = l1` copy `l1`.

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper).

Comment: You will be able to understand this much more intuitively If you look up  `pass by reference versus pass by value`. Even though here we are not using a function, the idea is the same. As a general rule, one can look at it this way - because the size of a collection is not known beforehand, a programming language will generally deal with the address of original collection rather than making a copy of it. You would have seen exact same behavior if you were assigning an array in java to three variables .

Answer (score 1):

It is because, when you assign a list to another list, it just creates a reference through another variable for the same storage.
l1,l2,l3 all refers to a same data.

when you remove a element from one list, the data gets reflected all the variable that reference that data.

in your second code, you could have got the same result with the below. basically you are removing value from 0 index from all the variables l1,l2,l3 by doing del l1[0]
'

```
l1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
l2 = l1
l3 = l2
del l1[0]

print(l3)
```

'

Answer (score 0):

```
l2 = l1
l3 = l2
```

`l2` points to the same memory location as `l1`, and consequently `l3` points to the same as `l2` and `l1`. Making any modifications in any of the three will reflect over all 3 variables.
When you do `l4 = l1[:]`, `l4` will become a copy of `l1` and not just point to the same location as `l1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
del l[:]
```

This clear the entire list. And because all of this variables point to the same memory location , like it is mentioned in the previous answer, you get that result.
Also take a look at the documentation. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

In python, use .copy() method to make a copy of a list, if you assign one list to another list it will share the same memory location.
[in the image you can find the difference between list.copy() and assign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHtE6.png)

```
lst1 = [1,2,3,4]
lst2 = lst1
lst3 = lst1.copy()
print("lst1 address : ", hex(id(lst1)))
print("lst2 address : ",hex(id(lst2)))
print("lst3 address : ",hex(id(lst3)))

lst1 address :  0x1f00c983f00
lst2 address :  0x1f00c983f00
lst3 address :  0x1f00a3127c0
```

If you delete elements in the list1, in list2 also it will delete because they share the same memory location.