# Python vs pandas - references and mutability

Tags: python, pandas, variable-assignment, immutability

Can someone help me understand what is happening here:

```
a = 1
b = a
b = 2
print(a)
print(b)
```

Here, obviously `a` will be unchanged because assigning `2` to `b` does not alter `a`.

In pandas, however:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
b = a
b.iloc[0,0] = 100
print(a)
print(b)
```

Now why do both `a` and `b` have `100` instead of `1`? I just found out I had been overwriting my original variables when I thought I was creating a new object in this way in pandas and had to use `b = a.copy()` to avoid it.

Comment: Does this answer your Question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper#:~:text=A%20shallow%20copy%20constructs%20a,objects%20found%20in%20the%20original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the pandas example, `b = a` does not create a copy of the DataFrame. There is a single DataFrame in memory, and both `b` and `a` are *references* to it. When you change that object, the change is visible in both `a` and `b` since they are pointing at the same thing.

If you want to create a copy of the data you could write:

```py
a = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
b = pd.DataFrame(a, copy=True)
```

This is true for most objects in Python-- usually a variable name is just pointing to an object in memory, and if you change the object, all references to it will be effected.

The first example is more of a special case. Integers are not mutable (can't be changed) so when you set `b = 2` you don't change the 1 into a 2, you just make `b` point at a different integer, while `a` is still pointing at 1.

Answer (score 1):

Because in your first example you are assigning to a and b two integers (1 and 2), which are two *different* *unmutable* objects in memory.

Whereas in your second second example, a and b are assigned the *same mutable* object (a dataframe). So calling the `iloc` method on b is the same as calling it on a.

Answer (score 0):

Had you used lists instead of integers, the result would have been different:

```
a = [1]
b = a
print (a,b)
b[0]=2
print (a,b)
```

Result:

```
[1] [1]
[2] [2]
```