# How can I modify a list without change the original list variable in Python?

Tags: python

```
items = [[1,2,3],[2,0,4],[3,4,1]]

def findzero(target):
    for i,lst in enumerate(target):
        for j,n in enumerate(lst):
            if n == 0:
                return [i, j]
    return (None, None)
        
def move_up(currState):
    result = currState[:]
    if findzero(result)[0] == 0:
        return result
    else:
        x = findzero(result)[0]
        y = findzero(result)[1]
        p = result[x - 1][y]
        result[x - 1][y] = 0
        result[x][y] = p
        return result
```

The result moved the 0 up but when I run the file, the 0 also moved up in the items variable. How can I move the zero up without change the original variable?

```
move_up(items)
Out[84]: [[0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [3, 4, 1]]

items
Out[85]: [[0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [3, 4, 1]]
```

I need items do not changed

Comment: See the `deepcopy` method from the [`copy` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), which will give you a copy of the lists instead of references to the originals.

Comment: ```import copy``` ```copy.copy``` and  ```copy.deepcopy``` in  https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Comment: You can also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper

Answer (score 1):

This

```
result = currState[:]
```

does create *shallow* copy, if you are sure that there always be exactly 2 levels (i.e. flat `lists` in single `list`) you might do

```
result = [i[:] for i in currState]
```

or equivalently

```
result = [i.copy() for i in currState]
```

if number of levels is not known in advance you might do

```
result = copy.deepcopy(currState)
```

(requires `import copy`)