# Why is this creation of a new pandas column causing a change in the original column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [2, 6, 7, 8, 2]})
```

|  | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 2 |

A function to create a new column being a cumulative sum (I'm aware of `cumsum()`, this was just a simple test before doing more complex functions):

```py
def funcadd(inputarr):
    for i in range(1, len(inputarr)):
        inputarr[i] = inputarr[i] + inputarr[i-1]
    return inputarr

df['new'] = funcadd(df['col1'].values)
```

|  | col1 | new |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 8 | 8 |
| 2 | 15 | 15 |
| 3 | 23 | 23 |
| 4 | 25 | 25 |

As you can see, for some reason `col1` gets modified despite never issuing a command to change it (?)

I've tried:

- immediately doing `arr1 = inputarr` in the function then only using `arr1` in the rest of the function
- doing `arr2 = df['col1'].values` before calling the function with `arr2`
- swapping `.values` with `.to_numpy`

Comment: try `df['new']=funcadd(df['col1'].copy())` and   col1 get modified is due to the fact that you are passing shallow copy of `df['col1']` into function for more info regarding copies refer to [What is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are better ways to do the cumulative sum in Pandas, as shown in the other answer but just to solve the issue here.

In this line

```
inputarr[i] = inputarr[i] + inputarr[i-1]
```

You are updating the values back to the original one, and since you haven't created the copy, it is writing back to the original dataframe.

if you want to avoid this, just create a copy, like this.

```
def funcadd(inputarr):
    c_inputarr = inputarr.copy()
    for i in range(1, len(inputarr)):
        c_inputarr[i] = c_inputarr[i] + c_inputarr[i-1]
    return c_inputarr

df['new'] = funcadd(df['col1'].values)
```

which returns

```
col1    new
0   2   2
1   6   8
2   7   15
3   8   23
4   2   25
```

Comment: how come `df['col1'].values = 0` doesn't work? do i only need to do `.copy()` if i'm passing it to a function?

Comment: do you want to assign 0 to all `df['col1'].values`

Comment: no, just wondering why i can't change the `df['col1'].values` outside the function but can when inside a function. just realised `df['col1'].values = 0` doesnt work inside function either, but for instance `df['col1'].values += 1` doesnt work outside the function, but if you pass it to a function as the arg `input` you can change it with `input += 1`