# Copied(sliced) list getting altered when I change the original one

Tags: python

```
    a = [1,[2,3]]
    b = a[:]
    a[1][1] = 5
    print(b)

#outputs [1,[2,5]]
```

Why is  b[1][1] getting reassigned?

Comment: `copy()` only works on the first layer; to copy nested mutable objects you need `deepcopy` from the `copy` module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper)

Comment: Yes,that pretty much answers it.Thank you very much, @blorgon