# Why does the original list change when I change the copied list (PYTHON)

Tags: python, list

So I have this simple code:

```
list = [[1,2],[4,5]]
list1 = list.copy() 
for i in range(len(list)):
    for j in range(len(list[i])):
        print(i,j, ":", list[i][j], "and", j,i, ":", list1[j][i])
        nr = input('Line {0}, Column{1}: ' .format(i+1, j+1) )
        list[i][j] = nr
        list1[j][i] = nr
        print(list,list1)
print(list1, list)
```

If I want the final result of the variable *list* to be the following matrix: `[[1,2],[3,4]]`, so the variable *list1* should be the transposed matrix: `[[1,3],[2,4]]`. Somehow the result is this: `[['1', '3'], ['3', '4']] [['1', '3'], ['3', '4']]`. Please someone help me. Thanks and have a good weekend

Comment: Why did you bother creating a copy of a list if you're going to just overwrite every element in the list?

Comment: @shrewmouse
Because I think is the easiest way instead of appending everytime elements and lists to the *list1*. For example, if the value of *list* is something like this: [[x,y],[z,k]]. The *list1* will be [[x,y],[z,k]] and I just need to change the indexes to have the correct value: [[x,z],[y,k]] (transposed matrix of [[x,y],[z,k]]). Don't you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `copy.deepcopy`.

If your list is a list of integers or floats, `copy` would suffice but since you have list of lists, you need to recursively copy the elements inside the lists.

You can find more detailed answer here: [What is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper)