# How to assign an element from a 2D array to a new variable without changing its original value in python?

Tags: python

I want to take a value from a 2D array (so this value has a type of array) and assign it to a new variable. But when I make changes to this new variable, its original value in that 2D array also changes. I want to know if there is a correct way that I can do this?

Here is my example code.

```
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
b = a[1]
b.append(2)
a.append(b)
print(a)
print(b)
```

In the output, a, b will be

```
a = [[1], [2, 2], [3], [2, 2]]
b = [2, 2]
```

Where I don't want a[1] to be changed as well. If someone can help me figure this out?
Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17246693

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably one of the most confusing concept for beginner, when you are doing subscription slicing, `b = a[1]`, the reference to first array `a` has been passed to `b`, which you whatever action you do to `b`, will be done to `a[1]`. **unless you make a complete copy of the original array, any action to subscripted will lead to change in original**, therefore, whenever you want to work with array without changing its initial value, copy it manually.

```py
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
# in your case it is nested so it will be a bit intricate 
ac = list(map(lambda x:list(map(lambda y:y, x)), a))
b = ac[1]
b.append(2)
a.append(b)
print(a)
print(b)
# [[1], [2], [3], [2, 2]]
# [2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `a[1]` is an array, passing it to `b` will pass it **by reference** and not **by value**.
You can use

```
b = a[1].copy()
```

to make a new instance of `a[1]` without effecting the original `a[1]`.

Comment: It's a really easy way to do. Thanks!