# why does append not append the parameter

Tags: python, append, depth-first-search

I was doing a bit of Leetcode and do not understand why  `res.append(subset)` does not append the subset to res.
Could somebody explain the reason behind this?

```
def solve(arr):
    res = []
    def dfs(arr,subset):
        if len(arr) == 0:
            # why does the following line not append the subset to res?
            res.append(subset)
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            subset.append(arr[i])
            dfs(arr[:i] + arr[i+1:],subset)
            subset.pop()
    dfs(arr,[])
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have assumed that `res.append(subset)` will append the *items* in `subset`. Python assignments for compound objects behave differently and so appending a list to a list is not the same as appending the *values* of a list to a list.

In this example, `subset.pop()` is removing values from `subset` and hence `res`, so that finally `solve` returns a list of empty lists. To make minimal changes to your code, I suggest that you copy the data using `copy.deepcopy()`.

```python
import copy
def solve(arr):
    res = []
    def dfs(arr,subset):
        if len(arr) == 0:
            # copy, rather than reference
            res.append(copy.deepcopy(subset))
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            subset.append(arr[i])
            dfs(arr[:i] + arr[i+1:],subset)
            subset.pop()
    dfs(arr,[])
    return res
```

More information is available in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) and there are simple examples in [previous SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17246744)