# Python - removing element from dicts copy affects the original dict

Tags: python, dictionary, copy

I am copying a dict and removing element from it. But this is affecting the original dict:

```
ugraph = {0: {1}, 1: {0, 2}, 2: {1, 3}, 3: {2}}
print(ugraph)
graph = ugraph.copy()
graph[0].remove(1)
print(ugraph)
```

gives the output:

```
{0: {1}, 1: {0, 2}, 2: {1, 3}, 3: {2}}
{0: set(), 1: {0, 2}, 2: {1, 3}, 3: {2}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper). Also [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184710/4046632).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you need to use deepcopy in that case.

```
from copy import deepcopy
...
graph = deepcopy(ugraph)
```

`copy` doesn't work here because you have a dict of mutable object(in your case dictionaries).

Answer (score 0):

```
 graph = ugraph.copy()
```

does a shallow copy of the object. What you need to perform is a deep copy which can be done using:

```
import copy
graph = copy.deepcopy(ugraph)
```

While copy.copy() will do a shallow copy, copy.deepcopy() performs a deepcopy.

The main difference between deepcopy and shallow copy is as follows:

- A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the
  extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
  the original.
- A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively,
  inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

You can go through this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper) for more explanation.