# How to use pipeline for multiple target language translations with M2M model in Huggingface?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, machine-translation, large-language-model

The [M2M model](https://huggingface.co/facebook/m2m100_418M) is trained on ~100 languages and able to translate different languages, e.g.

```
from transformers import pipeline

m2m100 = pipeline('translation', 'facebook/m2m100_418M', src_lang='en', tgt_lang="de")
m2m100(["hello world", "foo bar"])
```

[out]:

```
[{'translation_text': 'Hallo Welt'}, {'translation_text': 'Die Fu Bar'}]
```

But to enable multiple target translations, user have to initialize multiple pipelines:

```
from transformers import pipeline

m2m100_en_de = pipeline('translation', 'facebook/m2m100_418M', src_lang='en', tgt_lang="de")

m2m100_en_fr = pipeline('translation', 'facebook/m2m100_418M', src_lang='en', tgt_lang="fr")


print(m2m100_en_de(["hello world", "foo bar"]))
print(m2m100_en_fr(["hello world", "foo bar"]))
```

[out]:

```
[{'translation_text': 'Hallo Welt'}, {'translation_text': 'Die Fu Bar'}]
[{'translation_text': 'Bonjour Monde'}, {'translation_text': 'Le bar Fou'}]
```

#### Is there a way to use a single pipeline for multiple target languages and/or source languages for the M2M model?

I've tried this:

```
from transformers import pipeline

m2m100_en_defr = pipeline('translation', 'facebook/m2m100_418M', src_lang='en', tgt_lang=["de", "fr"])

print(m2m100_en_defr(["hello world", "foo bar"]))
```

But it throws the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_28/3374873260.py in <module>
      3 m2m100_en_defr = pipeline('translation', 'facebook/m2m100_418M', src_lang='en', tgt_lang=["de", "fr"])
      4 
----> 5 print(m2m100_en_defr(["hello world", "foo bar"]))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/text2text_generation.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    364               token ids of the translation.
    365         """
--> 366         return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/text2text_generation.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    163         """
    164 
--> 165         result = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    166         if (
    167             isinstance(args[0], list)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py in __call__(self, inputs, num_workers, batch_size, *args, **kwargs)
   1088                     inputs, num_workers, batch_size, preprocess_params, forward_params, postprocess_params
   1089                 )
-> 1090                 outputs = list(final_iterator)
   1091                 return outputs
   1092             else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/pt_utils.py in __next__(self)
    122 
    123         # We're out of items within a batch
--> 124         item = next(self.iterator)
    125         processed = self.infer(item, **self.params)
    126         # We now have a batch of "inferred things".

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/pt_utils.py in __next__(self)
    122 
    123         # We're out of items within a batch
--> 124         item = next(self.iterator)
    125         processed = self.infer(item, **self.params)
    126         # We now have a batch of "inferred things".

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    626                 # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    627                 self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 628             data = self._next_data()
    629             self._num_yielded += 1
    630             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    669     def _next_data(self):
    670         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 671         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    672         if self._pin_memory:
    673             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data, self._pin_memory_device)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     56                 data = self.dataset.__getitems__(possibly_batched_index)
     57             else:
---> 58                 data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     59         else:
     60             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     56                 data = self.dataset.__getitems__(possibly_batched_index)
     57             else:
---> 58                 data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     59         else:
     60             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/pt_utils.py in __getitem__(self, i)
     17     def __getitem__(self, i):
     18         item = self.dataset[i]
---> 19         processed = self.process(item, **self.params)
     20         return processed
     21 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/text2text_generation.py in preprocess(self, truncation, src_lang, tgt_lang, *args)
    313         if getattr(self.tokenizer, "_build_translation_inputs", None):
    314             return self.tokenizer._build_translation_inputs(
--> 315                 *args, return_tensors=self.framework, truncation=truncation, src_lang=src_lang, tgt_lang=tgt_lang
    316             )
    317         else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/m2m_100/tokenization_m2m_100.py in _build_translation_inputs(self, raw_inputs, src_lang, tgt_lang, **extra_kwargs)
    351         self.src_lang = src_lang
    352         inputs = self(raw_inputs, add_special_tokens=True, **extra_kwargs)
--> 353         tgt_lang_id = self.get_lang_id(tgt_lang)
    354         inputs["forced_bos_token_id"] = tgt_lang_id
    355         return inputs

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/m2m_100/tokenization_m2m_100.py in get_lang_id(self, lang)
    379 
    380     def get_lang_id(self, lang: str) -> int:
--> 381         lang_token = self.get_lang_token(lang)
    382         return self.lang_token_to_id[lang_token]
    383 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/m2m_100/tokenization_m2m_100.py in get_lang_token(self, lang)
    376 
    377     def get_lang_token(self, lang: str) -> str:
--> 378         return self.lang_code_to_token[lang]
    379 
    380     def get_lang_id(self, lang: str) -> int:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

One would have expected the output to look something like this instead:

```
{"de": [{'translation_text': 'Hallo Welt'}, {'translation_text': 'Die Fu Bar'}]
 "fr": [{'translation_text': 'Bonjour Monde'}, {'translation_text': 'Le Foo Bar'}]
}
```

#### If we use multiple pipelines, are the model mmap and shared? Will it initialize multiple models with multiple tokenizer pairs? Or will it initialize a single model with multiple tokenizers?

Comment: Sorry, I just noted the bounty yet. Are you looking for a different solution? A custom pipeline or a wrapper can avoid the additional call-parameter.

Comment: Yes, I think there are other solutions to allow multilingual processing, e.g. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11Wml-dOasQTuUYtk7dwKuU6B7bnQhwAq?usp=sharing and manipulating https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.10.1/_modules/transformers/generation_utils.html#GenerationMixin.generate but I'm overthinking it.

Comment: There should be some other way to use this https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.15.0/src/transformers/generation_logits_process.py#L559 in the decoding but it's a rabbit hole to dig in. It's better to just treat the tokenizers as separate functions (for most users)

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR (and recommended):**

[src_lang](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.TranslationPipeline.__call__.src_lang) and [tgt_lang](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.TranslationPipeline.__call__.tgt_lang) are `__call__` parameters and you can therefore change the target language while calling the pipeline:

```py
print(m2m100_en_de(["hello world", "foo bar"], tgt_lang="fr"))
print(m2m100_en_fr(["hello world", "foo bar"]))
```

Output:

```
[{'translation_text': 'Bonjour Monde'}, {'translation_text': 'Le bar Fou'}]
[{'translation_text': 'Bonjour Monde'}, {'translation_text': 'Le bar Fou'}]
```

**More detailed answer:**

This will load the model twice:

```py
from transformers import pipeline

m2m100_en_de = pipeline('translation', 'facebook/m2m100_418M', src_lang='en', tgt_lang="de")

m2m100_en_fr = pipeline('translation', 'facebook/m2m100_418M', src_lang='en', tgt_lang="fr")
print(id(m2m100_en_de.model))
print(id(m2m100_en_fr.model))
```

Output:

```
140447096860288
140447751061024
```

You can get around that to some(!) extent by passing the model directly instead of the model identifier string:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, pipeline

t = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/m2m100_418M")

m = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("facebook/m2m100_418M")


m2m100_en_de = pipeline('translation', model=m, tokenizer=t, src_lang='en', tgt_lang="de")
m2m100_en_fr = pipeline('translation', model=m, tokenizer=t, src_lang='en', tgt_lang="fr")
print(m2m100_en_de(["hello world", "foo bar"]))
print(m2m100_en_fr(["hello world", "foo bar"]))
print(id(m2m100_en_de.model))
print(id(m2m100_en_fr.model))
```

Output:

```
[{'translation_text': 'Hallo Welt'}, {'translation_text': 'Die Fu Bar'}]
[{'translation_text': 'Bonjour Monde'}, {'translation_text': 'Le bar Fou'}]
139674945076768
139674945076768
```

Please note, that I do not recommend this as you will still have duplicate entities in your memory. It is just to give you an idea and show you a way that results in fewer duplicates compared to your original attempt. Maybe also check this StackOverflow post: [What is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper)