# I'm confused about how objects in shallow copy and deep copy are referenced

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, deep-copy, shallow-copy

**Shallow_Copy**

```
foo = [1, 2, []] 
bar = foo.copy() 
foo[0] is bar[0] 
foo[2] is bar[2]
```

```
True 
True
```

Does this mean they both reference to the same objects?
However, they behave differently when I modify them.

```
bar[0] = 0 
print(foo)
```

```
[1, 2, []]
```

```
bar[-1].append(3)
print(foo)
```

```
[1, 2, [3]]
```

if foo[0] and bar[0] are referencing the same object, when I modified bar[0] why did foo[0] stay the same? And when I modified bar[2], foo[2] changed

**Deep_Copy**

```
foo = [1, 2, []] 
bar = copy.deepcopy(foo)
foo[0] is bar[0] foo[2] is bar[2]
```

```
True 
False
```

Additionally, why foo[2] and bar[2] don't reference the same object here

Comment: Have you read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the answer. For the second question, I guess I'm more confused because foo[0] and bar[0] still reference to the same object even when using deep copy

Comment: @Aaron There's no need to create a new object for an integer. The value is not mutable so it will never change.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental source of confusion here is *which object are you actually mutating*. The following line:

```
bar[0] = 0
```

Mutates `bar`, not `bar[0]`. On the other hand,

```
bar[-1].append(3)
```

Mutates `bar[-1]`, since `.append` is a mutator method.

But you would see *the same behavior if you did the equivalent thing*:

```
>>> foo = [1, 2, []]
>>> bar = foo.copy()
>>> foo[-1] = [3]
>>> foo, bar
([1, 2, [3]], [1, 2, []])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments:

you can see the unique (identities) id's of the items with the `id()` method. *"This is guaranteed to be unique among simultaneously existing objects"*.

So the code modified to this will be clearer:

```py
foo = [1, 2, []] 
bar = foo.copy() 
print(foo[0] is bar[0]) 
print(foo[2] is bar[2]) 


print('foo id:', id(foo))
print('bar id:', id(bar))


print('bar[0] id:', id(bar[0]))

print('foo:', foo)

bar[-1].append(3)

print('bar:', bar)
```

which returns this:

```
True
True
foo id: 2526001813312
bar id: 2526001811840
bar[0] id: 140706948506408
foo: [1, 2, []]
bar: [1, 2, [3]]
```

In particular, you can now see that the id's are different. So they are in fact different objects.

So modifications to `bar` will not modify `foo` and visa versa.

For the deepcopy part, the code requires an import and a modification like this shows what is happening.

```py
import copy
foo = [1, 2, []] 
bar = copy.deepcopy(foo)
print('foo:', foo)
print('bar:', bar)

print(foo[0] is bar[0]) 
print(foo[2] is bar[2])
print([] is [])
```

which returns this:

```
foo: [1, 2, []]
bar: [1, 2, []]
True
False
False
```

bascially `foo[2]` and `bar[2]` are empty lists.
we can see from `print([] is [])` that we get `False`.

Here is a link to the docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy

Comment: I'm not really sure what this demonstrates that wasn't already clear from using `foo[0] is bar[0]` etc

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, because this breaks the code down for the OP [1] to see the difference in the memory addresses and then [2] also a fundamental usage error and explanation for the deep copy...