# How does Python/Pandas "know" if you want to use a Python or Pandas function when the function name is the same?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy

*Note: I am asking this question because I want to get a deeper understanding of how things work in the background. I got into programming as a "side gig" so there are many many things I do not know or understand, and that bugs me. I only know how to use Python no other languages. I typically use Jupyter Notebooks in DataSpell.*

**Topic:**
In python there is a `.copy()` operation that creates a shallow copy (which, as I understand it, does not copy the object, but creates a reference/points to the object, so basically you just make another variable that can access the same object, and it was the same ID(?)), then there is a `.deepcopy()` operation that truly copies the object, which i guess means that in memory this object will have it's own place and if changes are made it will not affect the original object.

**Warming up to the question:**
In Pandas there is a `.copy()` function as well. It allows you to make a (deep) copy of eg. a dataframe as apposed to assigning a variable to the same dataframe object (`df2 = df1` will just point it to the same dataframe, while `df2 = df1.copy()` will make a deep copy of that frame. If you make changes to df2 in the latter example, it will not affect df1, but it will in the former example). But:

**Actual question:**
How does Python and/or Pandas "know" which `.copy()` you are using? I assume that if you use `.copy()` on non-Pandas objects, then it will use the Python shallow copy? And somehow, when `.copy()` is used on a DataFrame or other Pandas object, it "knows" that it should use the Pandas method? I am curious in general to learn/understand how the code is read/interpreted, but also ask this question for a practical reason:

If I want to copy for example a dictionary that contains several DataFrames, how can I know if `df_dict_copy = df_dict.copy()` will copy or shallow copy the dictionary?

Thanks for any answers and explanations, also feel fee to go super nerdy and deep because I am curious and interested in how this stuff works under the hood.

Some more background on me and my work that is not really important for the current question, but gives an idea of what I actually use Python for:

I am a doctor and a researcher. My current project uses a moderately large metabolomic dataset to predict various diseases and symptoms. I am working on different preprocessing methods and using various machine learning algorithms to predict binary outcome variables (yes/no, 1/0), and the datasets are approximately 6000 rows x 900 features (though after one-hotting some features, there are over 3000 additional columns as sparce matrices). Binary classification algorithms are used, mainly those available from Scikit-Learn, though I have also experimented with XGBoost, CatBoost and LightGBM. To prepare the data i use Numpy, Pandas and Scikit-Learn.

I just want to be certain that i am creating real copies when i use .copy()

and also if there are other methods that have the same name across libraries, I would like to know if there is something I should be doing to make sure the correct method is used etc.

Comment: *"In python there is a .copy() operation that creates a shallow copy (which, as I understand it, does not copy the object, but creates a reference/points to the object, so basically you just make another variable that can access the same object, and it was the same ID(?)),"* The behaviour you describe there ("making another variable that can access the same object") sounds more like what happens when you do `new = orig`, rather than the shallow copy you get when you do `new = orig.copy()`.

Comment: It would be useful to read this question: it doesn't directly discuss Pandas objects, but covers the foundations well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper

Comment: Yes that was useful thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `.copy()` method on a panda DataFrame, you are using this method: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html

This 'copy()' method belongs to the DataFrame class (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html). General information about classes in Python can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

When you call a class method on a concrete object, i.e. `df.copy()` Python will evaluate the type of the object (at runtime, as Python is dynamically typed) and use the method that is specified in the class definition. (This is a tiny bit simplified).

If `df` is an object of type `DataFrame`, the `.copy()` method defined in the class definition of the `DataFrame` class will be used. If the object `df` is of any other type, then the method of this other type/class will be used.

The main thing is: The `copy()` method in each case has the same name, but belongs to a different class.

Another example. Say you have 2 classes and the following code:

```
class A:
    def say(self):
        return 'hello A'

class B:
    def say(self):
        return 'hello B'

a = A()
b = B()

print(a.say())
```

What will be the output?

Comment: Maybe this is also usefull: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Comment: I would like to add that python's own .copy() method is also a class method (virtually everything in Python is a class in some way). However, the way python works is that it works through the classes from "bottom" to "top". This means that if the direct class (in this case a DataFrame) has a copy method it will take it, if not it will look at what it inherits from and see if that class contains a copy method. Thus always the next class method in the inheritance hierarchy is picked.

Comment: Jan_B what you added is also something that my question asks. AlexanderWeiss's answer is good too but missies that and also misses the last part, which was the most important: what happens when you use .copy() on a dictionary that contains DataFrames? The ChatGPT answer below answer that question but I don't know if it can be trusted. Perhaps I can find out by checking thee ID of a copy of a dictionary with dataframes?

Comment: I checked, and the IDs for the dict and the copied dict are different so i guess that makes the ChatGPT answer wrong? So is it using the pandas method then? And if yes, then again it seems that the way Python figures out which method to use is not as strait forward as in the explanations above?

Comment: Perhaps the Python library copy method is not used because it has not been imported?

Comment: @Glogg when you say "Python library copy method", do you mean `copy.copy()` (a module-level function that would require the module `copy` to be imported)? Or the `.copy()` methods of individual builtin classes (list, dict) etc?

Comment: @Glogg *"the IDs for the dict and the copied dict are different"* For your purposes, I think what is of interest would be the `id()` of the *dataframes within* the copied dict, not of the copied dict itself.

Comment: @Glogg If you use the `copy()` method on a dict, then the `copy()` method of the Dictonary Class is used. This has nothing to do with the objects inside the dictionary. @slothrop's comment is important here. Two different dictionaries can point to the same objects (in your case dataframes). This means, you can have two different dictionaries, at two different memory addresses, containing pointers to the same(!) objects.

Comment: omg thank you for clarifying this. So how do i make a copy of a dictionary containing dataframes so that all the dataframes inside are also copied? I would like to safely change those dataframes experimentally without changing the originals.

Comment: And what is even the point of a shallow copy? I don't understand why making a copy does not automatically make a deep copy...

Comment: And yes, I checked the IDs of the dataframes inside the copied dictionary and they are the same. That is super scary and saved me some trouble. I tried copying the dictionary using copy.deepcopy() and that gave the dataframes in the copied dictionary a new ID.