# Duplicate value in python dictionary while running a loop

Tags: python

I am running some remote commands on multiple devices using pexpect python module. Here is the code:

```
import pexpect
import sys

devices = ['10.10.10.10', '10.10.10.11']
commands = ['cmd1','cmd2']

command_out = {}
final_dict = {}

for dev in devices:
    child = pexpect.spawn('ssh user@' + dev)
    child.pexpect('assword')
    child.sendline('mypass')
    child.expect('#')
    for cmd in commands:
        child.sendline(cmd)
        child.expect('#')
        command_out[cmd] = child.before
    child.sendline('exit')
    final_dict[dev] = command_out

print(final_dict)
```

The issue is same command output is repeated for both the devices.

expected output:

```
{10.10.10.10: {cmd1: output1_for_first_device, cmd2: output2_for_first_device}, 10.10.10.11: {cmd1: output1_for_second_device, cmd2: output2_for_second_device}}
```

the actual output I am getting is:

```
{10.10.10.10: {cmd1: output1_for_second_device, cmd2: output1_for_second_device}, 10.10.10.11: {cmd1: output1_for_second_device, cmd2: output1_for_second_device}}
```

So the output of the last device is getting repeated for every device.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper In your code, `final_dict[dev] = command_out` is an assignment: it doesn't create a copy of `command_out`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: define `command_out = {}` inside the for loop.

Current problem: the dictionary `final_dict` has the same reference for `command_out` for both devices, so the final values of `command_out` is reflected in the `final_dict`.

Minimal example to demonstrate your problem:

```py
d2 = {}
d1 = {}

for i in range(2):
    d1["foo"] = i
    d2[i] = d1

print(d2)
```

Output: `{0: {'foo': 1}, 1: {'foo': 1}}`
This is your "actual" output.

But moving the `d1` inside the loop forces python to create a new dict.

```py
d2 = {}

for i in range(2):
    d1 = {}
    d1["foo"] = i
    d2[i] = d1

print(d2)
```

Output: `{0: {'foo': 0}, 1: {'foo': 1}}`
This is your "expected" output.