# Why is the list that I'm feeding into my function being edited?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have 2 functions that I run a list of dictionary items into. In each function, I created a temporary version that would be the one being manipulated within the function so that the original doesn't get edited. But for some reason, the original is in fact being edited. Below are the two functions that I believe are the culprits:

```
def basic_booster_pack(card_list):
    foil_chance = 0.22388059701 > random.random()
    mythic_chance = 0.125 > random.random()
    pack_cards = card_list
    pack_cards,basic_lands = seperate_basic_land(pack_cards)
    common_cards = [card for card in pack_cards if card['rarity']=='common']
    uncommon_cards = [card for card in pack_cards if card['rarity']=='uncommon']
    rare_cards = [card for card in pack_cards if card['rarity']=='rare']
    mythic_cards = [card for card in pack_cards if card['rarity']=='mythic']
    common_slots = [random.sample(common_cards,10) if foil_chance else random.sample(common_cards,9)]
    uncommon_slots = random.sample(uncommon_cards,4)
    rare_slot = [random.choice(rare_cards) if mythic_chance else random.choice(mythic_cards)]
    land_slot = random.choice(basic_lands)
    pack = common_slots[0] + uncommon_slots + rare_slot + land_slot
    return pack
```

```
def seperate_basic_land(card_list):
    temp = card_list
    basic_land_list = ['Plains', 'Island', 'Swamp', 'Mountain', 'Forest', 'Wastes']
    basic_land_index = [i for i in range(len(temp)) if temp[i]['name'] in basic_land_list]
    basic_lands = [temp[land] for land in basic_land_index]
    for j in sorted(basic_land_index, reverse=True):
        temp.pop(j)
    return temp, basic_lands
```

The only fix that I thought might have helped was instead of just running the function as:

```
 basic_booster_pack(ala)
```

I switched the code to:

```
basic_pack = basic_booster_pack(ala)
print(basic_pack)
```

but the original "ala" list was still being edited.

Comment: `temp = card_list` is an **assignment**, not a **copy**. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper. It simply makes two variable names refer to the same object.

Comment: Also useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment