# Setting two arrays equal

Tags: python, arrays

```
array1=[0,1,2]
array2=array1
array2[0]=234234
print array1
```

OUTPUT:

```
[234234, 1, 2]
```

Why does python change 'array1'? Shouldn't it just change array2?
How can I prevent python from changing array1 when I change array2?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Don't worry too much about the downvoters – some people think that every duplicate or beginner question should be downvoted. But besides being a duplicate this is a fine question: it's clear what the question is and it shows pithy code that clearly demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 15):

`array1` and `array2` are *the same object*.  That's why changing either changes the other.  If you want to *copy* the object, here's one way to do it:

```
array2 = array1[:]
```

See [more on this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438938/python-copy-through-assignment).

Answer (score 6):

Use slice notation to copy like this

```
array2 = array1[:]
```

Or you can use `list` function

```
array2 = list(array1)
```

When you assign one list to another list, a new list will not be created but both the variables will be made to refer the same list. This can be confirmed with this program.

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array2 = array1
print id(array1), id(array2)
```

They both will print the same id. It means that they both are the same (If you are from C background you can think of them as pointers (In CPython implementation they really are pointers, other implementations choose to print unique ids - Please check kojiro's comment)). Read more about `id` [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id). When you do

```
array3 = array1[:]
array4 = list(array1)
print id(array1), id(array3), id(array4)
```

you ll get different ids, because new lists will be created in these cases.

Comment: +1 FWIW, that `id`s are like pointers is an implementation detail specific to CPython. If the Python interpreter is different they might not be. But they'd still be guaranteed to have the same value in this case, even if that value isn't the memory address of the list.

Comment: omg thank u i own u my life.  also were u the person who downvoted me because if so i will definitely consider retracting the previous statement.

Comment: @user2875270 Nope. I didnt downvote :) This is a beginner question which we all had. So, I just indicated that the question has already been answered in another thread.

Comment: @kojiro Thats true, that is why included the python doc for `id` in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

`array1` and `array2` are two names for the same list, since that's how you set them. If you don't want this, copy the list using one of the following methods:

```
array2 = array1[:] 
array2 = list(array1)
```