# Slice notation isn't creating a new copy in memory

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've imported an image as RGB using scipy and imread(). Say I want to separate out the "R" component and copy it to a new object in memory. The code below works:

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.misc as misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 
pic = misc.imread("ARBITRARY IMAGE.png");

r = pic[:,:,0].copy()
r[0,0] = 0
print(r[0,0])
print(pic[0,0,0])
```

Outputs the expected:

```
0
255
```

However I got there by the following path, and I don't know why they don't work:

```
r = pic[:,:,0]
r[0,0] = 0
print(r[0,0])
print(pic[0,0,0])
```

outputs:

```
0
0
```

Fair enough, I took the syntax cue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) and it involves using a slice like `b = a[:]` instead of a single layer. How about:

```
r = pic[:]
r[0,0,0] = 0
print(r[0,0,0])
print(pic[0,0,0])
```

or to add an extra step:

```
r = pic[:]
r= r[:,:,0]
r[0,0] = 0
print(r[0,0])
print(pic[0,0,0])
```

Still outputs:

```
0
0
```

It is an array not a list, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341365/setting-two-arrays-equal) for arrays implies that this syntax should be okay. Basically, how come a new object isn't created in memory when I use the slice notation in my examples? I assume I am missing something else, and my googling just seems to tell me the syntax should work. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Variable `pic` probably isn't an ordinary array, but some object with an overloaded slice operator that doesn't create a copy, but rather a view referencing the same data. E.g. numpy doesn't like creating copies as well, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [other question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341365/setting-two-arrays-equal) uses incorrect terminology; it's asking about Python *lists*, whereas you're using a Numpy array. Slicing a list does give you a copy of the chosen range, but [slicing an array gives you a view](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) instead. Changes you make to the view are reflected in the original.

With Numpy arrays, you need to use `copy()` to get a separate copy that you can change without affecting the original. This is a design choice, because Numpy arrays can often be very large and you wouldn't want to copy them inadvertently.

Comment: be forwarned if you are using 32 bit python np.array.copy can be an expensive operation wrt memory (numpy requires contiguous memory)

Comment: @David Duh I didn't even think to take a guess that they were using the wrong terms.

Joran, Not that it's necessary for me here, but do you have an alternative? Or should I just try to avoid making copies with such an array