# Issue assigning new values to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am having an issue when I assign an array of data to a new variable and try to change elements within the new variable. For instance, if I have the array y = [1,2,3], I set the value of a new array y1 to be: y1 = y. Then, I want to change the first element of y1 to be 9 without changing y. However, when I execute the command y1[0] = 9, it changes the first element of y1 and y. How can I change y1 without changing y?

Here is an example of my code,

```py
import numpy as np
y = np.array([1,2,3])
y1 = y
y1[0] = 9
print(y1)
print(y)
```

I expected the output to be:

```py
array([9,2,3])
array([1,2,3])
```

However, the code returns the following

```py
array([9,2,3])
array([9,2,3])
```

Comment: With a simple stackoverflow search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341365/setting-two-arrays-equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `y.copy()` to create a new copy of the array:

```
import numpy as np

y = np.array([1,2,3])
y1 = y.copy()
y1[0] = 9

print(y1)
print(y)
```

Output:

```
[9 2 3]
[1 2 3]
```