# Why does list.remove() in python access other lists?

Tags: python, list

Can someone please explain how this is possible??

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,4,3,2,2]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2]
>>> b = a
>>> b.remove(1)
>>> b
[2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2]
>>> a
[2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2]
```

How is the `remove` method able to access `a` when I called it on `b`? I can work around this by importing copy and copying the list that way but If someone can explain how the above is possible that would be amazing!

Blockquote

Comment: Because b is a copy of a and share the same memory address

Comment: You didn't create copies, you created additional references to the list.

Comment: `b  = a[:]` will do the job

Comment: Read http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hi again! I dont think this was a duplicate of that question because he was asking if someone could explain why this is the way it is. Not how to copy a list

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, I now understand. Still new to Python

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2438938/3001761

Comment: @LaPepita If you do `print 'Memory address of a: ', id(a)
print 'Memory address of b: ', id(b)` you will see that the lists are referencing the same memory address so when you remove it from b, you remove it from a since they are coming from the same memory location

Comment: @heinst: but the underlying issue is that they thought they had created a copy. They had not. This crops up time and again.

Comment: @heinst: if you read the other question carefully, you'll see that it covers the exact same ground.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think hes honestly asking why this is, because he states how he can work around it, but ok!

Comment: @heinst: there is even a [specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27091494) on the other post explaining why not copying creates another reference to the same object.