# flatten arrays in a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, view, flatten

I have multiple numpy masked arrays `arr0, arr1, ..., arrn`.

I put them in a list `arrs = [arr0, ..., arrn]`.

I want to flatten these arrays et put a mask on them. I did something like:

```
for arr in arrs:
    arr = np.ravel(arr)
    arr[mask] = ma.masked
```

I do not understand when Python make copies and when it is just a pointer. This `for` loop does not flatten the `arr0, ..., arrn`, (whereas ravel outputs a view and not a copy) it just flattens the variable `arr`, although it does change their mask !

As I understand it, `arr` is a view of the elements in the list `arrs`, so when I change elements of `arr` it changes the elements of the corresponding array in the list. But when I assign a new value to `arr` it does not change the original array, even if the assignement is supposed to be a view of this array. Why ?

**Edit with an example**:

Arrays to flatten:

```
arr0 = masked_array(data=[[1,2],[3,4]], mask=False)
arr1 = masked_array(data=[[5,6],[7,8]], mask=False)
mask = [[False,True],[True,False]]
```

Expected output:

```
arr0 = masked_array(data=[[1,--],[--,4]], mask=[[False,True],[True,False]])
arr1 = masked_array(data=[[5,--],[--,8]], mask=[[False,True],[True,False]])
```

I'd like to do this in a loop because I have a lot of arrays (15 more or less), and I want to use the arrays name in the code. Is there no other way than do to:

```
arr0 = np.ravel(arr0)
...
arrn = np.ravel(arrn)
```

Comment: Could you add a numerical example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: the problem is with list iterator.  You can't assign it within the loop.

Comment: `arr = np.ravel(arr)` creates a new (flattened) view to `arr` and reassigns the name *arr* to point to that created view. Plain assignment just [reassigns names to point to something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438938/python-copy-through-assignment). As you've noted `ravel()` creates a view and so `arr[mask] = ma.masked` does modify the original as well.

Comment: Assigning and mutating are different operations. Variables are always just references. Assigning a name to a new value always just changes what that reference refers to, not the original value.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1032]: arr0 = np.ma.masked_array(data=[[1,2],[3,4]], mask=False)    
In [1033]: arr1 = np.ma.masked_array(data=[[5,6],[7,8]], mask=False)
```

This is the basic way of iterating over a list, applying some action to each element, and collecting the results in another list:

```
In [1037]: ll=[arr0,arr1]    
In [1038]: ll1=[]
In [1047]: for a in ll:
    a1=a.flatten()   # makes a copy
    a1.mask=mask
    ll1.append(a1)

In [1049]: ll1
Out[1049]: 
[masked_array(data = [1 -- -- 4], mask = [False  True  True False],
        fill_value = 999999), 
        masked_array(data = [5 -- -- 8], mask = [False  True  True False],
        fill_value = 999999)]
```

Often that can be writen a list comprehension

```
 [foo(a) for a in alist]
```

but the action here isn't a neat function

If I use `ravel` instead, `a1` is a view (not a copy), and applying mask to it changes the mask of `a` as well - the result is changed masks for `arr0`, but no change in shape:

```
In [1051]: for a in ll:
   ......:     a1=a.ravel()
   ......:     a1.mask=mask
```

(the same happens with your `a=a.ravel()`.  The `a=` assigns a new value to `a`, breaking the link to the iteration value.  That's true for any Python iteration.  It's best to use new variable names inside the iteration like `a1` so you don't confuse yourself.)

Essentially the same as

```
In [1054]: for a in ll:
   ......:     a.mask=mask
```

I can change the shape in the same in-place way

```
In [1055]: for a in ll:
   ......:     a.shape=[-1]   # short hand for inplace ravel
   ......:     a.mask=mask   

In [1056]: arr0
Out[1056]: 
masked_array(data = [1 -- -- 4],
             mask = [False  True  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Here's a functional way of creating new arrays with new shape and mask, and using it in a list comprehension (and no change to `arr0`)

```
[np.ma.masked_array(a,mask=mask).ravel() for a in [arr0,arr1]]
```

Understanding these alternatives does require understanding how Python assigns iterative variables, and how numpy makes copies and views.

Comment: just wanted to point out that the **none np way** can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/2139007. for those who wonder :)