# Drop function in Pandas is changing original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using drop in pandas with an inplace=True set. I am performing this on a duplicate dataframe, but the original dataframe is also being modified.

```
df1 = df
for col in df1.columns:
   if df1[col].sum() > 1:
      df1.drop(col,inplace=True,axis=1)
```

This is modifying my 'df' dataframe and don't seem to understand why.

Comment: You don't know a very important concept. Pandas `DataFame` is a **mutable** type object. For better understanding check this out: [https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747]

Comment: I do, I usually use the copy function as stated in another answer. Just didn't use it here.

Comment: "I am performing this on a duplicate dataframe" Your code says otherwise. You simply have two names for the same dataframe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Copy Through Assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438938/python-copy-through-assignment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `df1 = df.copy()`. Otherwise they are the same object in memory.

However, it would be better to generate a new DataFrame directly, e.g.

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.sum() <= 0]
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I forgot that.

Comment: It'd be less memory to use `drop` without `inplace=True` and do the assignment in a single step