# (Python) Modify several lists in-place

Tags: python, list, in-place

I'd like to remove duplicates from several lists (in-place). Have tried the following but failed ([Python Compiler](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/)):

```
a = [1, 2, 2]
b = [3, 4, 4]
c = [5, 6, 6]

print('===previous')
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
print(id(c))
print('---previous')

for l in (a, b, c):
  l = list(dict.fromkeys(l))
  print('===middle')
  print(id(l))
  print('---middle')

print('===after')
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
print(id(c))
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print('---after')
```

I know this is because ([Python Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438938/does-python-make-a-copy-of-objects-on-assignment?fbclid=IwAR0dlYRwWCLUdGdWzI4RwYQYC8IenaXCt5Swnhhib_U319qtwaXC3GlIMoE))

> Variables (names) are just references to individual objects.

Just want to ask if any efficient way can achieve this goal, thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to remove duplicates in the individual lists? So your desired output would be ```a = [1, 2], b = [3, 4], c = [5, 6]``` ?

Comment: `l = list(dict.fromkeys(l))` That creates a _new_ list.  You're not actually modifying the original lists.

Comment: @goalie1998 Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, I know ```l = list(dict.fromkeys(l))``` doesn't modify the original lists. Just want to if any way can efficiently apply the same action to several lists in-place. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the value and not the variable name. If you need to modify a dynamic amount of lists, then you can override all values in the list by taking a full slice of each list:

```
for my_list in (a, b, c):
     my_list[:] = set(my_list)
```

Comment: The first method won't work if OP wants to use the original list variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/set.html). Duplicates are not allowed in sets:

```
a = set(a)
b = set(b)
c = set(c)
```

If you need them to be in a list again:

```
a = list(set(a))
b = list(set(b))
c = list(set(c))
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use for-loop to modify all lists, like:
```for l in (a, b, c):
    l = set(l)```
. I know the above doesn't work. Just want to know if any way is able achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 2, 2]
b = [3, 4, 4]
c = [5, 6, 6]


a=list(dict.fromkeys(a))
b=list(dict.fromkeys(b))
c=list(dict.fromkeys(c))


print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Comment: Mohammed Jubayer, thanks for your answer.