# Why does random.shuffle() change pointed variable?

Tags: python

I have this bit of code

```
def find():
temp = liked
shuffle(temp)
if temp == liked:
    return True
```

By debugging I've seen that after shuffle(temp) also the liked variable changes. Why does it happen?

Comment: Because `temp` and `liked` are different names for the same object.

Comment: Yes but why does the "liked" variable change if i change temp...

Comment: So how do I create a copy of liked not linked to that object

Comment: This should actually error out, as `liked` does not exist. The provided snippet seems to be incomplete. The behaviour you describe depends on the data type you're referencing. It is likely copied by reference not copied by value.

Answer (score 0):

`temp = liked` is an assignment. It points `temp` to `liked` so that when you  say `shuffle(temp)`, `temp` is just referring `shuffle()` back to `liked`.

**assignment:** `temp = liked`

**copy:** `temp = liked.copy()`

You will find an in depth conversation about it here: [Does Python make a copy of objects on assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438938/does-python-make-a-copy-of-objects-on-assignment)